# How to time a script in DOS?

Tags: time, dos

How do you time a script in the DOS prompt?

The *NIX equivanlent would be:

```
$ time myscript

real 0m0.886s
user 0m0.846s
sys 0m0.031s

$
```

Is there a DOS equivalent to this? Thanks

Comment: Are you really talking about DOS, or a command-shell for windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to measure execution time of command in windows command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 5):

you can put this at the start and end of your batch:

```
echo %time%
```

Comment: Warning: don't use it directly on the command (`echo %time% & myprog & echo %time%`), because the expansion for both is done before the command is even executed.

Answer (score 5):

This is a DOS batch script that will compute the time difference for you rather than just doing `echo %time%`.

The following code will work fine as long as your "timed user section" doesn't take more than 24 hours to run.  Please be forgiving or give me suggestions, it's a work in progress that I spent about an hour on.

Replace "PAUSE" with the call to your script to time your own code.

DOS BAT FILE FOLLOWS:

Note: was edited to fix issue with leading zeros being octal rather than decimal.

Note: was edited to handle running over "midnight" hour wraparound and to put leading zeros in output.

```
@echo off
@rem --------------------------------------------
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

set start_time=%time%
echo Beginning at: %start_time%
echo Running Timed Batch File
echo.

@rem echo %*  <-- Extension for all args -- easier than following line
@rem echo %0 %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9 ... ...

@rem DO YOUR WORK HERE -- see "call" / PAUSE is here to "fake" work
@rem call userscript.bat %*
PAUSE

set stop_time=%time%
echo.
echo Timed Batch File Completed
echo Start time: %start_time%
echo Stop time : %stop_time%


set TEMPRESULT=%start_time:~0,2%
call:FN_REMOVELEADINGZEROS
set start_hour=%TEMPRESULT%
@rem
set TEMPRESULT=%start_time:~3,2%
call:FN_REMOVELEADINGZEROS
set start_min=%TEMPRESULT%
@rem
set TEMPRESULT=%start_time:~6,2%
call:FN_REMOVELEADINGZEROS
set start_sec=%TEMPRESULT%
@rem
set TEMPRESULT=%start_time:~9,2%
call:FN_REMOVELEADINGZEROS
set start_hundredths=%TEMPRESULT%

set TEMPRESULT=%stop_time:~0,2%
call:FN_REMOVELEADINGZEROS
set stop_hour=%TEMPRESULT%
@rem
set TEMPRESULT=%stop_time:~3,2%
call:FN_REMOVELEADINGZEROS
set stop_min=%TEMPRESULT%
@rem
set TEMPRESULT=%stop_time:~6,2%
call:FN_REMOVELEADINGZEROS
set stop_sec=%TEMPRESULT%
@rem
set TEMPRESULT=%stop_time:~9,2%
call:FN_REMOVELEADINGZEROS
set stop_hundredths=%TEMPRESULT%

set /A start_total=(((((%start_hour%*60)+%start_min%)*60)+%start_sec%)*100)+%start_hundredths%
set /A stop_total=(((((%stop_hour%*60)+%stop_min%)*60)+%stop_sec%)*100)+%stop_hundredths%

set /A total_time=%stop_total% - %start_total%

set /A total_hundredths=%total_time% %% 100
set total_hundredths=00%total_hundredths%
set total_hundredths=%total_hundredths:~-2%
set /A total_time=%total_time% / 100

set /A total_sec="%total_time% %% 60"
set total_sec=00%total_sec%
set total_sec=%total_sec:~-2%
set /A total_time=%total_time% / 60

set /A total_min="%total_time% %% 60"
set total_min=00%total_min%
set total_min=%total_min:~-2%
set /A total_time=%total_time% / 60

set /A total_hour="%total_time% %% 60"
@rem Handle if it wrapped around over midnight
if "%total_hour:~0,1%"=="-" set /A total_hour=%total_hour% + 24

echo Total time: %total_hour%:%total_min%:%total_sec%.%total_hundredths%

@rem --------------------------------------------
@rem Exit the BAT Program
endlocal
goto END

@rem --------------------------------------------
@rem FN_REMOVELEADINGZEROS function
@rem  Used to remove leading zeros from Decimal
@rem  numbers so they are not treated as Octal.
:FN_REMOVELEADINGZEROS
if "%TEMPRESULT%"=="0" goto END
if "%TEMPRESULT:~0,1%" NEQ "0" goto END
set TEMPRESULT=%TEMPRESULT:~1%
goto FN_REMOVELEADINGZEROS

@rem --------------------------------------------
@rem BAT PROGRAM / FUNCTION FILE EXIT
:END
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use timeit.exe from the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD&displaylang=en) .  You also get a crapload of other useful tools and Unix command ports.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Rob>timeit sleep 3

Version Number:   Windows NT 5.1 (Build 2600)
Exit Time:        2:40 pm, Thursday, December 10 2009
Elapsed Time:     0:00:03.296
Process Time:     0:00:00.015
System Calls:     7576
Context Switches: 1974
Page Faults:      1072
Bytes Read:       6172
Bytes Written:    11086
Bytes Other:      144432
```

Comment: This approach was the easiest for me with one annoyance.  I was timing a dos batch file that is located in c:\windows\system32.  When I tried to time it, I had to enter the fully qualified path to the .bat even though it was in my system path.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a third party EXE for help, [timer.exe](http://www.gammadyne.com/cmdline.htm#timer) from [Gammadyne](http://www.gammadyne.com/) is very useful.

```
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
FOR /F %%G IN ('timer') DO SET start_time=%%G

@rem Do your work Here
call userscript.bat %*

timer %start_time% "Total time"
endlocal
```