# How to slice a pandas DataFrame by position?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a Pandas Data Frame object that has 1000 rows and 10 columns. I would simply like to slice the Data Frame and take the first 10 rows. How can I do this? I've been trying to use this:

```
>>> df.shape
(1000,10)
>>> my_slice = df.ix[10,:]
>>> my_slice.shape
(10,)
```

Shouldn't my_slice be the first ten rows, ie. a 10 x 10 Data Frame? How can I get the first ten rows, such that `my_slice` is a 10x10 Data Frame object? Thanks.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html?highlight=head#pandas.DataFrame.head

```
df2 = df.head(10)
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 108):

You can also do as a convenience:

`df[:10]`

Comment: This seems to not copy the column names for me.

Answer (score 19):

There are various ways to do that. Below we will go through at least three options.

In order to keep the original dataframe `df`, we will be assigning the sliced dataframe to `df_new`.

At the end, in section **Time Comparison** we will show, using a random dataframe, the various times of execution.

---

**Option 1**

```
df_new = df[:10] # Option 1.1

# or

df_new = df[0:10] # Option 1.2
```

---

**Option 2**

Using [`head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

```
df_new = df.head(10)
```

> For negative values of n, this function returns all rows except the last n rows, equivalent to `df[:-n]` [[Source]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html).

---

**Option 3**

Using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

```
df_new = df.iloc[:10] # Option 3.1

# or

df_new = df.iloc[0:10] # Option 3.2
```

---

**Time Comparison**

For this specific case one has used [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) to measure the time of execution.

```
       method                   time
0  Option 1.1 0.00000120000913739204
1  Option 1.2 0.00000149995321407914
2    Option 2 0.00000170001294463873
3  Option 3.1 0.00000120000913739204
4  Option 3.2 0.00000350002665072680
```

[image]

As there are various variables that might affect the time of execution, this might change depending on the dataframe used, and more.

---

**Notes:**

- Instead of `10` one can replace the previous operations with the number of rows one wants. For example

  ```
  df_new = df[:5]
  ```

  will return a dataframe with the first `5` rows.
- There are additional ways to measure the time of execution. For additional ways, read this: [How do I get time of a Python program's execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1557571/7109869)
- One can also adjust the previous options to a lambda function, such as the following

  ```
  df_new = df.apply(lambda x: x[:10])

  # or

  df_new = df.apply(lambda x: x.head(10))
  ```

  Note, however, that there are [strong opinions on the usage of .apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/7109869) and, for this case, it is far from being a required method.

Answer (score 14):

`df.ix[10,:]` gives you all the columns from the 10th row. In your case you want everything up to the 10th row which is `df.ix[:9,:]`. Note that the right end of the slice range is inclusive: http://pandas.sourceforge.net/gotchas.html#endpoints-are-inclusive

Comment: this is depricated

Comment: .ix is not working u shall delete it, "df[:10]" is enough

Answer (score 4):

`DataFrame[:n]` will return first n rows.