# pandas data frame transform INT64 columns to boolean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, boolean

Some column in dataframe df, df.column, is stored as datatype int64.

The values are all 1s or 0s.

Is there a way to replace these values with boolean values?

Answer (score 84):

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype('bool')
```

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(0,1,size=5), 
                  columns=['foo'])
print(df)
#    foo
# 0    0
# 1    1
# 2    0
# 3    1
# 4    1

df['foo'] = df['foo'].astype('bool')
print(df)
```

yields

```
     foo
0  False
1   True
2  False
3   True
4   True
```

---

Given a list of `column_names`, you could convert multiple columns to `bool` dtype using:

```
df[column_names] = df[column_names].astype(bool)
```

If you don't have a list of column names, but wish to convert, say, all numeric columns, then you could use

```
column_names = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns
df[column_names] = df[column_names].astype(bool)
```

Comment: How to let pandas detect this automatically? If there are only 0 and 1.. then make it boolean?

Comment: How to do this for all applicable columns?

Comment: Tried `df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype('bool')`. The **boolean** value is defaulted to `True`. How to default the **boolean** as `False`?

Comment: @user12379095 I solved the problem using a simple converter on the column like lambda x: x if x else 0
Maybe not the most efficient way but it works.

Answer (score 4):

There are various ways to achieve that, below one will see various options:

1. Using [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)
2. Using [`pandas.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)
3. Using [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)
4. Using [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)
5. Using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

As OP didn't specify the dataframe, in this answer I will be using the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 'col2': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'col3': [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], 'col4': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]})

[Out]:

   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     0     1     0
1     0     0     1     0
2     0     1     1     0
3     1     0     0     0
4     0     1     1     1
```

We will consider that one wants to change to boolean only the values in `col1`. If one wants to transform the whole dataframe, see one of the notes below.

In the section **Time Comparison** one will measure the times of execution of each option.

---

**Option 1**

Using [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) as follows

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].map({1: True, 0: False})

[Out]:

    col1  col2  col3  col4
0   True     0     1     0
1  False     0     1     0
2  False     1     1     0
3   True     0     0     0
4  False     1     1     1
```

---

**Option 2**

Using [`pandas.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) as follows

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(bool)

[Out]:

    col1  col2  col3  col4
0   True     0     1     0
1  False     0     1     0
2  False     1     1     0
3   True     0     0     0
4  False     1     1     1
```

---

**Option 3**

Using [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html), with one of the following options

```
# Option 3.1
df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace({1: True, 0: False})

# or

# Option 3.2
df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace([1, 0], [True, False])


[Out]:

    col1  col2  col3  col4
0   True     0     1     0
1  False     0     1     0
2  False     1     1     0
3   True     0     0     0
4  False     1     1     1
```

---

**Option 4**

Using [`pandas.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and a custom lambda function as follows

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: True if x == 1 else False)

[Out]:

    col1  col2  col3  col4
0   True     0     1     0
1  False     0     1     0
2  False     1     1     0
3   True     0     0     0
4  False     1     1     1
```

---

**Option 5**

Using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) as follows

```
import numpy as np

df['col1'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 1, True, False)

[Out]:

    col1  col2  col3  col4
0   True     0     1     0
1  False     0     1     0
2  False     1     1     0
3   True     0     0     0
4  False     1     1     1
```

---

**Time Comparison**

For this specific case one has used [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) to measure the time of execution.

```
       method                   time
0    Option 1 0.00000120000913739204
1    Option 2 0.00000220000219997019
2  Option 3.1 0.00000179999915417284
3  Option 3.2 0.00000200000067707151
4    Option 4 0.00000400000135414302
5    Option 5 0.00000210000143852085
```

[image]

---

**Notes:**

- There are strong opinions on using `.apply()`, so [one might want to read this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54432583/7109869).
- There are additional ways to measure the time of execution. For additional ways, read this: [How do I get time of a Python program's execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1557571/7109869)
- To convert the whole dataframe, one can do, for example, the following

  ```
  df = df.astype(bool)

  [Out]:

      col1   col2   col3   col4
  0   True  False   True  False
  1  False  False   True  False
  2  False   True   True  False
  3   True  False  False  False
  4  False   True   True   True
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Reference: Stack Overflow unutbu (Jan 9 at 13:25), BrenBarn (Sep 18 2017)

I had numerical columns like age and ID which I did not want to convert to Boolean.  So after identifying the numerical columns like unutbu showed us, I filtered out the columns which had a maximum more than 1.

```
# code as per unutbu
column_names = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns 

# re-extracting the columns of numerical type (using awesome np.number1 :)) then getting the max of those and storing them in a temporary variable m.
m=df[df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns].max().reset_index(name='max')

# I then did a filter like BrenBarn showed in another post to extract the rows which had the max == 1 and stored it in a temporary variable n.
n=m.loc[m['max']==1, 'max']

# I then extracted the indexes of the rows from n and stored them in temporary variable p.
# These indexes are the same as the indexes from my original dataframe 'df'.
p=column_names[n.index]

# I then used the final piece of the code from unutbu calling the indexes of the rows which had the max == 1 as stored in my variable p.
# If I used column_names directly instead of p, all my numerical columns would turn into Booleans.
df[p] = df[p].astype(bool)
```