# Log time of execution for each line in Python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, profiling

I have a Python script which executes fairly straightforward from the first to the last line with plain logic. The script performance is very different on a couple of machines with different environments, so I am trying to find out which line of the code gives me a hard time.

I have seen [cProfiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) and some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-to-get-time-of-a-python-program-execution) (`timeit`) on recording time of execution for the whole function. I am, however, interested in finding out the time Python spent on executing each line of the code in my script.

The source code:

```
import math
result = pow(2,5)
newlist = []
newlist.append(result)
print newlist
```

What I want to get (number of row - time it took to execute in seconds):

```
1 - 0.04
2 - 0.01
3 - 0.06
4 - 0.08
5 - 0.1
```

**EDIT**: I have tried to use [hotshot](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hotshot.html), a standard library available, however I am getting an error message.

The source code I run:

```
import hotshot
import hotshot.stats

logfile = r"C:\testlog.prof"
prof_obj = hotshot.Profile(logfile,lineevents=True,linetimings=False)
prof_obj.start()
a = 1000
b = 2000
c = a + b
print c
prof_obj.stop()
prof_obj.close()

stats_obj = hotshot.stats.load(logfile) #getting error on this line *
stats_obj.strip_dirs()
stats_obj.sort_stats('time', 'calls')
stats_obj.print_stats(20)
```

---

```
*     for event in log:
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\hotshot\log.py", line 115, in next
    filename, firstlineno, funcname = self._stack[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

**EDIT:** I have found another example on using a hotshot from the Python Essential Reference book.

```
import hotshot
import hotshot.stats

def function_to_call():
    print "AA"
    print "BB"

logfile = r"C:\testlog.prof"
prof_obj = hotshot.Profile(logfile,lineevents=True,linetimings=True)
prof_obj.runcall(function_to_call)
prof_obj.close()

stats_obj = hotshot.stats.load(logfile)
stats_obj.sort_stats('time', 'calls')
stats_obj.print_stats()
```

However, this does not give me any information on execution per line of code, only per function call:

```
5 function calls in 0.012 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time, call count

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        4    0.012    0.003    0.012    0.003 <string>:6(write)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.012    0.012 c:\gis\temp\simple_hotshot.py:11(function_to_call)
        0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [line profiler module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/1.0b2) that might do what you are looking for.  It also has nice decorators that you can put over functions you want to profile on a line by line level.  You can read the docs [here](http://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/).

Also take a look at [`hotshot`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hotshot.html).  It looks like you can set the `linetimings` parameter to get what you are looking for.  I'm not sure `hotshot` will be supported in future versions, though.

Comment: Good one. Anything included in the core Python? There is a good chance I won't be able to install anything on one of the machines.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov  Added some more info.  I think you can get what you want with hotshot, and it is built in to Python.  Let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: thanks very much. I've tried this and updated my answer with the code and the error message. It is really hard to find any example usages of hotshot on the Internet, I've seen only the one that comes with the official Python docs. Any chance you could point out what's wrong with my code above?