# Would like to write code in idle that I have in Jupyter notebook. It is using Timeit

Tags: python

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndnQM.png)
big_array= np.random.rand(1000000)
%timeit  sum(big_array)

this code above is done in jupyter notebook
how do I use this code in idle

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### With IDLE

The most direct is to build the timer into your Python code and then run it using IDLE based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14452178/8508004):

Using IDLE as you do run this based on the code you provided:

```py
import time
start = time.process_time()
import numpy as np
big_array= np.random.rand(1000000)
sum(big_array)  
print(time.process_time() - start)
```

If you wanted to use Pyinstrument (see below section), that is possible, too. [The documentation](https://pyinstrument.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#profile-a-specific-chunk-of-code) suggests with your code that would be:

```py
from pyinstrument import Profiler
profiler = Profiler()
profiler.start()
import numpy as np
big_array= np.random.rand(1000000)
sum(big_array)  
profiler.stop()
profiler.print()
```

---

---

#### Alternative using Python installed on your system with the Python Profiler tool Pyinstrument and your code as a script

(I'm adding this because this is the more mature route. You won't really want weave the time/profiling into your code as you start develop more capable code and functions. And you probably won't use IDLE much down the road.)

The easiest is to make your code a script and then time it using pure Python and not Jupyter/IPython magics. I gather based on your code provided, you'd save your script, `my_script.py` with the following contents:

```py
import numpy as np
big_array= np.random.rand(1000000)
sum(big_array)
```

I tried using the `cProfiler` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30242546/8508004) and wasn't having much luck adapting that code example, and so I used a more modern profiler, [pyinstrument](https://github.com/joerick/pyinstrument), I had seen suggested by somebody much more knowledgeable about Python than myself. (Later, saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/582337/8508004) I could just use `python -m cProfile my_script.py` to use the cProfiler, but after using pyinstrument first I could quickly see why pyinstrument was recommended.)

I installed that easily with `pip install pyinstrument`. And then ran the following on the command line/terminal:

```bash
pyinstrument my_script.py
```

That's meant to be the equivalent of running `python my_script.py` on your command line/terminal, now with wrapping it in the pyinstrument profiling, see [the documentation](https://pyinstrument.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#profile-a-python-script).

You'll see lots of profiling information including the time:

```
jovyan@jupyter-binder-2dexamples-2drequirements-2dfg42zx6b:~$ pyinstrument my_script.py

  _     ._   __/__   _ _  _  _ _/_   Recorded: 15:05:41  Samples:  96
 /_//_/// /_\ / //_// / //_'/ //     Duration: 0.424     CPU time: 0.416
/   _/                      v4.1.1

Program: my_script.py

0.423 <module>  <string>:1
   [4 frames hidden]  <string>, runpy
      0.423 _run_code  runpy.py:64
      └─ 0.423 <module>  sum_test.py:1
         ├─ 0.224 <module>  numpy/__init__.py:1
         │     [231 frames hidden]  numpy, pickle, struct, <built-in>, pa...
         │        0.088 create_dynamic  <built-in>:0
         ├─ 0.176 sum  <built-in>:0
         │     [2 frames hidden]  <built-in>
         └─ 0.024 RandomState.rand  <built-in>:0
               [2 frames hidden]  <built-in>

To view this report with different options, run:
    pyinstrument --load-prev 2022-05-27T15-05-41 [options]
```

Add some more zeros to the number in `big_array= np.random.rand(1000000)` and you can really see the `sum()` step become the rate-limiting one in the whole process of running that code.