# Replace %timeit when not using Jupyter / iPython

Tags: python, jupyter, ipython, timeit

I am trying to understand the [Google JAX](https://github.com/google/jax) framework, which is a collection of tools to speed up various forms of (matrix) computations.

In all the examples (e.g. [official readthedocs.io](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/quickstart.html#auto-vectorization-with-vmap)) that I come across this is illustrated with comparing "naive" computations with JAX computations, using `%timeit`. I kept running into errors until I discovered that this is a Jupyter/iPython magic function.

I think Jupyter/iPython is an amazing tool, especially for communicating something (a paper, etc.). But for tinkering I prefer a tool like [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) or even [Thonny](https://thonny.org/), which makes it easier to keep track of what all the variables and functions in memory are.

What is the equivalent form of `%timeit` that I can use to replace `%timeit` in regular Python (from the `timeit` package I assume)?

Comment: use the timeit library

Comment: [itprorh65](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14249087/itprorh66) what would the exact command that is equivalent to %timieit (from the `timeit` library) be?

Comment: That would depend on what you want to do, suggest you read the timeit docs, and then when you have a specific issue ask a detailed question.  It isn't the job of Stackoverflow to do your work

Comment: [fastero - Python timeit CLI for the 21st century](https://github.com/wasi-master/fastero), or pyinstrument. For the latter, see an example with a script at the very bottom [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72407678/8508004).