# Compute inverse of 2D arrays along the third axis in a 3D array without loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, linear-algebra

I have an array `A` whose shape is `(N, N, K)` and I would like to compute another array `B` with the same shape where `B[:, :, i] = np.linalg.inv(A[:, :, i])`.

As solutions, I see `map` and `for` loops but I am wondering if `numpy` provides a function to do this (I have tried `np.apply_over_axes` but it seems that it can only handle 1D array).

with a `for` loop:

```
B = np.zeros(shape=A.shape)
for i in range(A.shape[2]):
    B[:, :, i] = np.linalg.inv(A[:, :, i])
```

with `map`:

```
B = np.asarray(map(np.linalg.inv, np.squeeze(np.dsplit(A, A.shape[2])))).transpose(1, 2, 0)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For an invertible matrix `M` we have `inv(M).T == inv(M.T)` (the transpose of the inverse is equal to the inverse of the transpose).

Since `np.linalg.inv` is broadcastable, your problem can be solved by simply transposing `A`, calling `inv` and transposing the result:

```
B = np.linalg.inv(A.T).T
```

For example:

```
>>> N, K = 2, 3
>>> A = np.random.randint(1, 5, (N, N, K))
>>> A
array([[[4, 2, 3],
        [2, 3, 1]],

       [[3, 3, 4],
        [4, 4, 4]]])

>>> B = np.linalg.inv(A.T).T
>>> B
array([[[ 0.4  , -4.   ,  0.5  ],
        [-0.2  ,  3.   , -0.125]],

       [[-0.3  ,  3.   , -0.5  ],
        [ 0.4  , -2.   ,  0.375]]])
```

You can check the values of `B` match the inverses of the arrays in `A` as expected:

```
>>> all(np.allclose(B[:, :, i], np.linalg.inv(A[:, :, i])) for i in range(K))
True
```

Comment: Wow, I would have never guessed that `inv` was broadcastable but now that I actually think about it, why not! Good work, sir/madam!

Comment: The last command throws a syntax error for me, I think the square bracket at the end should be a round bracket. otherwise +1

Comment: @Wolpertinger: thanks for the catch! I've fixed the syntax error.