# Pyramids and Oblique Cones in MEEP

Tags: python, geometry, meep

Apologies if this is not the right place for this question.

I've recently started using MIT's [MEEP](https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) software (Python3, on Linux). I am quite new to it and would like to mostly use it for photovoltaics projects. Somewhat common shapes that show up here are "inverted pyramid" and slanted (oblique) cone structures. Creating shapes in MEEP seems to generally be done with the [GeometricObject](https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python_User_Interface/#geometricobject) class, but they don't seem to directly support either of these structures. Is there any way around this or is my only real option simulating these structures by stacking small Block objects?

As described in my own "answer" posted, it's not too difficult to just define these geometric objects myself, write a function to check if it's inside the object, and return the appropriate material. How would I go about converting this to a MEEP GeometricObject, instead of converting that to a material_func as I've done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No responses, so I thought I'd post my hacky way around it. There are two solutions: First is as mentioned in the question, just stacking MEEP's Block object. The other approach I did was define my own class Pyramid, which works basically the same way as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25180294/12900038). Then, I convert a list of my class objects and MEEP's shape object to a function that takes a vector and returns a material, and this is fed as material_func in MEEP's Simulation object. So far, it seems to work, hence I'm posting it as an answer. However, It substantially slows down subpixel averaging (and maybe the rest of the simulation, though I haven't done an actual analysis), so I'm not very happy with it.

I'm not sure which is "better" but the second method does feel more precise, insofar that you have pyramids, not just a stack of Blocks.