# How to find if a 3d point is inside/on/outside of tetrahedron

Tags: c++, geometry, geometry-surface

I'm having school project in which I have to implement tetrahedron. I have to overload the >> , << , == to check if a **3d(x,y,z) point is in,on,outside of the tetrahedron**, which is represented by 3d points as well. How can I do that (the bold text, I don't know the theory for that)?

Comment: I'm struggling with understanding the theory.

Comment: You now just check if a point P is on the other side of the plane. The normal of each plane is pointing away from the center of the tetrahedron. So you just have to test against 4 planes.

Your plane equation looks like this: a*x+b*y+c*z+d=0 Just fill in the point values (x y z). If the sign of the result is >0 the point is of the same side as the normal, result == 0, point lies in the plane, and in your case you want the third option: <0 means it is on the backside of the plane. If this is fulfilled for all 4 planes, your point lies inside the tetrahedron.

Comment: a*x+b*y+c*z+d=0, so if I'm correct in this equation (x,y,z) stand for the coordinates for the point I'm checking. What does a,b,c,d stand for?

Comment: If you are interested in the mathematical basics https://math.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask. I don't think I'm versed enough to explain any of this, just found the duplicate. Maybe the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25180294/5105949) is clearer. Though it's in a C# not C++ that algorithm is the same.