# How can we check a point is within triangular pyramid?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, 3d, algebra

We made a function returns a point is within triangle. Now we want to go further than that. We want to check a point is in the volume of tetrahedral pyramid or not **with only coordinates**. For example, our pyramid's coordinates is `[(0, 0, 0), (3, 1, 4), (1, 4, 2), (6, 3, 5)]`. And our target point is `(1, 1, 0)`. It must return `false`. But if we made our point's `Z` is `1`, it must return `true`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179693/how-to-check-whether-the-point-is-in-the-tetrahedron-or-not

Comment: Also see http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/geometry/ptintet.html and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3698021/how-to-find-if-a-3d-point-is-in-on-outside-of-tetrahedron

Answer (score 0):

According to:
[Blackpawn](https://blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/)

A common way to check if a point is in a triangle is to find the vectors connecting the point to each of the triangle's three vertices and sum the angles between those vectors. If the sum of the angles is 2*pi then the point is inside the triangle, otherwise it is not. It works, but it is very slow.

Comment: OP solved the problem in 2D. Question is about going 3D.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach: calculate [signed volumes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Volume) of source tetrahedron and four tetrahedrons formed by point P and facets using the next determinants (I omit 1/6 factor).

All determinant values should have **the same sign** for inside points

```
for source
      | x1  x2  x3  x4 |
V =   | y1  y2  y3  y4 |
      | z1  z2  z3  z4 |
      | 1   1   1   1  | 

      | px  x2  x3  x4 |
V1 =  | py  y2  y3  y4 |
      | pz  z2  z3  z4 |
      | 1   1   1   1  | 

      | x1  px  x3  x4 |
V2 =  | y1  py  y3  y4 |
      | z1  pz  z3  z4 |
      | 1   1   1   1  |
```

and similar for V3, V4 using P coordinates in corresponding column

Comment: @Weylyn Is my answer still unclear?