# Django: Which way is better way to find(search) a equal data object?

Tags: python, django

I am implementing searching functions in `Django`, which of these would be better?

```
def same_cart_item_in_cart(cart, new_cart_item):
    already_exist_cart_item = cart.cartitem_set.filter(
        Q(variation__product=new_cart_item.variation.product),
        Q(variation=new_cart_item.variation),
        Q(width=new_cart_item.width),
        Q(height=new_cart_item.height),
    ).first()

    return already_exist_cart_item    # It can be None
```

Override `CartItem`'s `__eq__` first.

```
class CartItem(TimeStampedModel):
    cart = models.ForeignKey("Cart")
    variation = models.ForeignKey(Variation)
    # 벽화 너비
    width = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=1,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1)],
    )
    # 벽화 높이
    height = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=1,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1)],
    )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=1,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1)],
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.variation.product) + ' - ' + str(self.variation)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (
            self.variation.product == other.variation.product and
            self.variation == other.variation and
            self.width == other.width and
            self.height == other.height
        )
```

and then,

```
def same_cart_item_in_cart(cart, new_cart_item):
    for cart_item in cart.cartitem_set.all():
        if cart_item == new_cart_item:
            return cart_item

    return None
```

Comment: Have you ran any time benchmarks? And i believe that query is the better choice(<1> option), because you need to make one query instead of retrieving all object and then iterate through each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in the comment <1> option is better.

And it you are trying to save new instance and check it before saving, Django made it for you. You can add [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#unique-together) to your `Model` `Meta` and you it will raise error if you would try to save partly same object.

**UPDATE**

It should optimize your code with [using foregn key values directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/optimization/#use-foreign-key-values-directly)

So your code would be

```
def same_cart_item_in_cart(cart, new_cart_item):
    already_exist_cart_item = cart.cartitem_set.filter(
        Q(variation_id=new_cart_item.variation_id),
        Q(width=new_cart_item.width),
        Q(height=new_cart_item.height),
    ).first()

    return already_exist_cart_item
```

I removed `Q(variation__product=...)`, if `Variation` instance is the same, you don't need to query on its fields. And changed `Q(variation=...)` to `Q(variation_id=...)`

Comment: I use http://stackoverflow.com/a/1557584/3595632 and  <1> is much faster!

Comment: `unique_together` would be great but have a problem. If same instance exist, I have to re-calculate the `quantity`  like this : `instance.quantity += new_instance.quantity'... So that's why I couldn't use `unique_together`... Is there anything I can do for it?

Comment: @user3595632 i've updated answer, correct me if i'm wrong with penultimate sentence.

Comment: I'm trying to do with `unique_together` but had some problems in catching the exception propery when same item exists.... Maybe I have to do with your method...

Comment: @user3595632 what seems to be the problem? It says `ValidationError` is raised when such record exists. I want it to be clear, do you still want the duplicate record to be saved? And how you set `unique_together`? I think it should be `unique_together = ('variation', 'width', 'height')`

Comment: I set `unique_together = ('variation', 'width', 'height')`. But where should I catch the `ValidationError`? `clean()` or `full_clean()`?

Comment: Anyway, your answer do helps!

Comment: @user3595632 it should raise `ValidationError` when you are trying to `save()` it. So i think in your view or smth.