# time taken by code is an issue for python dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need help related to dataframe related time taken by following code.
it takes around 20 sec to complete dataset around 2000 records.

```
def findRe(leaddatadf, keyAttributes, datadf):
    for combs in itertools.combinations(atrList,
        len(atrList)-1):

        v_by =(set(atrList) - set(combs)) # varrying


    grpdatapf=datadf.groupby(combs)
    for name, group in grpdatapf:

        if(group.shape[0]>1):

            tmpgdf = leaddatadf[leaddatadf['unique_id'].astype(float).\
                isin(group['unique_id'].astype(float))]
            if(tmpgdf.shape[0]>1):

                tmpgdf['mprice']=tmpgdf['mprice'].astype(float)
                tmpgdf=tmpgdf.sort('mprice')

                tmpgdf['id'] = tmpgdf['id']
                tmpgdf['desc'] = tmpgdf['description']
                tmpgdf['related_id'] = tmpgdf['id'].shift(-1)
                tmpgdf['related_desc'] = tmpgdf['description'].shift(-1)
                tmpgdf['related_mprice'] = tmpgdf['mprice'].shift(-1)

                tmpgdf['pld'] = np.where(
                    (tmpgdf['related_price'].astype(float) > \
                        tmpgdf['mprice'].astype(float)),
                    (tmpgdf['related_price'].astype(float) - \
                        tmpgdf['mprice'].astype(float)) ,
                    (tmpgdf['mprice'].astype(float) - \
                        tmpgdf['related_mprice'].astype(float)))
                tmpgdf['pltxt'] = np.where(
                    tmpgdf['related_mprice'].astype(float) - \
                        tmpgdf['mprice'].astype(float)>0.0,'<',
                    np.where(tmpgdf['related_mprice'].astype(float)\
                        - tmpgdf['mprice'].astype(float)<0,'>','='))
                tmpgdf['prc_rlt_dif_nbr_p'] = abs(
                    (tmpgdf['pld'].astype(float) / \
                        ((tmpgdf['mprice'].astype(float)))) )
                tmpgdf['keyatr'] = str(atrList)
                tmpgdf['varying'] = np.where(1==1,
                    "".join(v_by ),'')# varrying

                temp = tmpgdf[['id',
            'desc', 'related_id',
            'related_desc', 'pltxt', 'pld',
            'prc_rlt_dif_nbr_p', 'mprice', 'related_mprice',
            'keyatr', 'varying']]

                temp = temp[temp['related_mprice'].astype(float)>=0.0]
                reldf.extend(list(temp.T.to_dict().values()))
    return pd.DataFrame(
                reldf, columns = ['id',
                    'desc', 'related_id',
                    'related_desc', 'pltxt', 'pld',
                    'prc_rlt_dif_nbr_p', 'mprice', 'related_mprice',
                    'keyatr', 'varying'])
```

Comment: I think Stackoverflow is not meant to be a code review site. This question isn't asking anything in particular, so I think it should be moved somewhere else.

Comment: then where should i ask about it

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

please print after every line how many ms it takes

use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1557584/2655092

and return with the lines that takes the most time

Comment: Time taken by getting tmpdf - 0.00083160400390625 -
Time taken by reset_index - 0.0006613731384277344 -
Time taken by mprice to float - 0.0002810955047607422 -
Time taken by time taken by sort by mprice - 0.0007467269897460938 -
Time taken by id - 0.0015559196472167969 -
Time taken by desc - 0.0017049312591552734 -

Comment: Time taken by related_id - 0.0018208026885986328 -
Time taken by related_desc - 0.0018434524536132812 -
Time taken by related_mprice - 0.0015764236450195312 -
Time taken by pld - 0.0020411014556884766 -
Time taken by pltxt - 0.0022830963134765625 -
Time taken by prc_rlt_dif_nbr_p - 0.001756429672241211 -
Time taken by keyatr - 0.0015103816986083984 -
Time taken by varying - 0.00200653076171875 -
Time taken by allcomb - 0.0007736682891845703 -
Time taken to convert df to list of dict - 0.00047779083251953125 -

Comment: hi Jm I have added time taken by each line. total  14 key atr list size is there

Answer (score 0):

You're using `astype(float)` very often. Every time you use it - a copy of the series is created. You could try to set `dtype=float` at the very beginning when you're trying to load the dataframe - that way you're only converting the series to float once - and not on every iteration :)

Let me know if this helps

Comment: thanks sir I will do that, other thing I wanted to improve , i have 14-1 unique combinations and for each I am grouping and finding the relations between current and next row.