# Pygame exiting after certain time

Tags: python, pygame

I have a pygame code which I wanted to be executed for only X seconds, I tried

```
sleep(10)
pygame.quit()
```

It just continues to run.

Comment: Don't use `time.sleep` in GUI frameworks.

Comment: `pygame.quit` won't quit the program. It will initialize all pygame modules.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
sleep(10)
pygame.quit()
```

to

```
from sys import exit
sleep(10)
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: This is invalid because `sleep()` comes from `time.sleep()`, which pauses the entire program for the amount of seconds passed

Answer (score 0):

Though the program could exit a few milliseconds off your actual time, you could try to use the method defined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1557584/4052384) and constantly check by resetting `time.time()` repeatedly in a `while` loop which should be fairly easy since you are using PyGame after all:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

while True:
    if time.time() - start_time() >= 10:
        pygame.quit()
```