# How to make a loop that calculates running time?

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, time

I'm making a simple client/server program in Python 3 and in the client I would like a clock or printout of the running time. I'm trying to make it in a loop that starts at the beginning of the program, but in a thread so the rest of the code keeps going.

```
    class time_thread():
        def run(self):

            loop = 0

            while (zetime > -1):
                print(zetime);
                zetime = zetime + 1;
    time_thread.start()
zetime = 0
```

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't work. It says:

> time_thread has no attribute start()

I'm new to this and haven't used threads before, so I'm not sure how to go about this. Is there a better way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution

Comment: What do you expect? You didn't define a `start` method, or extend `Thread` or anything...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
import time, sys

zetime = 0
while (zetime > -1):
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + str(zetime))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
    zetime = zetime + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all , to use Thread module, you have to inherit the class Thread on your class, so you can use their methods like start.
To calculate time, you can use datetime.

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

start_time  = datetime.now()   
sleep(5) # code that you want to calculate.
end_time = datetime.now()   
print(end_time - start_time)
```

Just place this

Answer (score 0):

So let's say you define a function elapsed_time such as:

```
import time, sys
def elapsed_time(time_start):
    ''' time_start: a time.time()
        Goal: print the elapsed time since time_start '''
    # Allow to stop the counting once bool_time = False in the main program
    global bool_elapsed_time
    # loop while the condition 
    while bool_elapsed_time == True:
        # Note: erase and write below does not work in spyder but in a shell yes
        print ("Elapsed time: {} seconds".format(int(time.time() - time_start))),
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print ("\r"),
        time.sleep(1)
    # erase the line with elapsed time to clean the shell at the end
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print ("\r"),
```

Then in your program:

```
import threading
bool_elapsed_time = True
t = threading.Thread(name='child procs', target=elapsed_time, args=(time.time(),))
t.start()
## Here add the job you want to do as an example:
time.sleep(10)
bool_elapsed_time = False #to stop the elapsed time printing
```

Should do the job you want to do.

Note: I used python 2.7 so it might be slightly different with 3.x