# faster approach: assigning vs appending in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Which one is faster?

*first approach*: assigning values to an empty dataframe

```
df = pd.DaraFrame(index = range(5), columns=['A','B'])
for i in range(5):
   df.iloc[i] = i , i*i
```

*second approach*: appending values to dataframe

```
df = pd.DaraFrame(columns=['A','B'])
for i in range(5):
   df.iloc[i] = i , i*i
```

Comment: df['A'],df['B']=df.index,df.index**2

Comment: This is something you can test yourself with [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html), though neither of those are actually efficient ways to perform that calculation as Wen points out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it yourself using the time module.

See this link to see how to use calculate execution time:

[How do I get time of a Python program's execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution)