# Get Total Runtime In Milliseconds

Tags: python, time

How can I find the total runtime of my Python code in milliseconds? I know I can use `import time` and `time.time()` but that is assuming that my program takes at least a tenth of a second to run. How can I get the total runtime of the code if the total execution time is 1 millisecond?

For Example:

```
start_time = time.time()
print("Hello World")
print(time.time() - start_time) # Returns the time in scientific notation.
```

Comment: Show your code attempts

Comment: I have just added it. Forgot to do that.

Comment: Possibly the duplicate of this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution

Try with `time.clock()`