# Save frames of live video with timestamps

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I want to capture the frames of video with timestamps in real time using Raspberry pi. The video is made by USB webcam using `ffmpeg()` function in python code. How do I save the frames of video which is currently made by USB webcam in Raspberry pi?

I tried using three functions of opencv. cv2.VideoCapture to detect the video, `video.read()` to capture the frame and `cv2.imwrite()` to save the frame.Here is the code, the libraries included is not mentioned for conciseness.

```
  os.system('ffmpeg -f v4l2 -r 25 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 out.avi')
  video=cv2.VideoCapture('out.avi')
  ret, frame=video.read()
  cv2.imwrite('image'+str(i)+'.jpg',frame)     
  i+=1
```

The code saves the frames of video which was previously made by webcam. It is not saving the frames of video which is currently being recorded by webcam.

Comment: What do mean `currently being recorded` ? Do you mean video still under recording and not yet flushing to a file?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#capture-video-from-camera), you can access the camera with `camera=cv2.VideoCapture(0)`. 0 is an index of the connected camera. You may have to try a different index, but 0 usually works.
Similar as a video file you can use `ret, frame = camera.read()` to grab a frame. Always check the `ret` value before continuing processing a frame.
Next you can add text to the frame as described [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_drawing_functions/py_drawing_functions.html#adding-text-to-images).
You can use [time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1557584/10699171) or [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) to obtain a timestamp.
Finally save the frame.

Note: if you use `imwrite` you will quicky get a LOT of images. Depending on your project you could also consider saving the frames as video-file. Explained [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#saving-a-video).

Edit after comment:

This is how you can use `time.time()`. First import the time module at the top of your code. `time.time()` returns the number of seconds since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00`.
So to get a timestamp, you have to store the starttime - when the program/video starts running.
Then, on every frame, you call time.time() and subtract the starttime. The result is the time your program/video has been running. You can use that value for a timestamp.

```
import time

starttime = time.time()

# get frame
timestamp = time.time() - starttime
cv2.putText(frame,timestamp,(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.CV_AA)
```

Comment: I want to either save the frame such that Timestamp is written on it or the image is saved with the Timestamp as its name. I tried to add timestamp by time.time() function in cv2.putText() function and It just writes time.time() on every frame rather than the timestamp. font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(frame,'time.time()',(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.CV_AA).                                   Also I tried using time.time() in place of image name of cv2.imwrite() function and its not adding timestamp either.        cv2.imwrite('time.time()'+str(i)+'.jpg',frame)

Comment: You should not put it in quotes. It is a function, not a string. I modified the answer to show you how to use time.time()