# How to get the time which a code has spent within a particular if-elif construct

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, time

[image]I am providing a piece of code of project for iris localization. So here I would like to get amount of time that a person spends looking at a particular direction. So moreover I want to get entire time a code spends in a specific if-elif construct.

I have tried something using timeit module.But I was not able to get the time when the code enters the if section and the time at which it leaves the while loop.

```
                thresh = (five_eye[1]-one_eye[1])
                print("thresh:",thresh)
                # if 13<thresh <16:
                #     print('CENTER')
                #     cv2.putText(frameClone, 'CENTER', 
(90,40),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                #     single_eye_state.append(index)
                #     single_eye_state.append('CENTER')
                if 10<thresh<=13:
                    start = timeit.timeit()
                    print('Looking Down 1 Feet')
                    cv2.putText(frameClone,'Looking Down 1 Feet', 
(90,40),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                    single_eye_state.append(index)
                    single_eye_state.append('DOWN1')
                    end = timeit.timeit()
                    print(end - start)
                elif 7<thresh<=10:
                    start = timeit.timeit()
                    print("Looking Down 2 Feet")
                    cv2.putText(frameClone,'Looking Down 2 Feet', 
(90,40),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
                    single_eye_state.append(index)
                    single_eye_state.append('DOWN2')
                    end = timeit.timeit()
                    print(end - start)
```

Need the total time a code spends in a while loop.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution) should help you time your function. Also you are not calculating the spent time in your elif, so you wont get any output if you end in the elif part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one of the section will run, either if or elif. So it is better to just wrap the if-elif construct and get the time taken like:

```
start = timeit.timeit()
if condition:
    ....
elif:
    ....
end = timeit.timeit()
print(end-start)
```

In case you want total time over multiple sections:

```
total = 0
if condition:
    start = timeit.timeit()
    ....
    end = timeit.timeit()
    total += end - start
elif:
    start = timeit.timeit()
    ....
    end = timeit.timeit()
    total += end - start
print(total)
```

**Note:** Only one of the section will run i.e, either if on elif. I added the code just for clarity.

Comment: Thank you Yash. Actually I would like to get the time in every conditions, Just now I have made some changes so check it out my code once again and I will expect your valuable reply.

Comment: Your edited code looks ok to me, what problem are you facing with it?

Comment: Now it is printing just printing the execution time of two statements in the if condition. So just imagine a person is looking down 1 feet for a duration of  10 seconds so the first if condition should print 10 sec, but now it is printing the execution time every instant but I want the overall duration. I will provide you some screenshots. Thank you Yash once again for your comment.

Comment: 1. if it is just running in the if statement it is because only the if condition is running which is the natural way. 2. For overall time, I have already hinted in my code

Comment: Great.. Thank you!

Comment: Yah... I mean it's working and I am able to get the time at all instants, so what I am going to try is taking the first time and the final time and calculate the duration. Can you give any hint for it, like should I append the times to a list or not, else whatever it may be.

Comment: Oh now I get it. Instead of using list, you can simply calculate the time in each section and add it to the total time. I have updated my answer with sample