# Merge CSV files with respect to schema of any one of those

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have multiple csv files (around 100s) which has same headers in each of those. However, the sequence of header in every file is different. How shall I merge them in one csv where right data is placed in right column

Ex:

1. csv has headers : {header1, header2, header3, ... header10}
2. csv has headers : {header2, header5, header10, ... header9}

I want to merge them such that resultant.csv looks like {header1, header2, header3, ... header10} but has data rightly mapped into each column. Like header1 data from 1.csv is correctly mapped with header1 data from 2.csv and so on.

Comment: Read data using pandas then append them is what you need https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Can you be more specific?

Comment: load all the csv to dataframes, put them all in a list, df = pd.concat(csv_list, sort = True)

Comment: Thanks @PhungDuyPhong. It worked

Comment: @trigonom. Yours also worked. My only question is, is this efficient way?

Comment: no idea, take all the methods that worked and check run time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution

Answer (score 4):

It's not Python but it could solve your goal. Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), a great command line utility, the command is

```
mlr --csv unsparsify ./*.csv >output.csv
```

If you want also to reorder the fields

```
mlr --csv unsparsify ./*.csv then reorder -f header1, header2, header3, ... header10 >output.csv
```