# how to measure efficient algorithm

Tags: python, performance, measurement

I have multiple algorithms in python that solves the same problem.
I would like to know which one is more efficient.
How can I make create an environment that both algorithms will have the same amount of resources (so I can tell which one is faster).
each algorithm can take days to finish, so if there is a way to do that and still work on the computer, that will be better.

Comment: Can you use a smaller problem size, so that the algorithms won't take so long to finish?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to theoretically calculate the Big O notation for all your algorithms.

You should check out what [Big O](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation&ved=2ahUKEwibuOqtwMDoAhUGxTgGHVc6DlMQFjAOegQIDRAf&usg=AOvVaw0leG6q2JkJR22b-QV1qPth) is here if you don't know

Or you could check out this video
[YouTube video for Big O](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DD6xkbGLQesk&ved=2ahUKEwibuOqtwMDoAhUGxTgGHVc6DlMQt9IBMA96BAgNECc&usg=AOvVaw0-XT5QnpEjOyrbTs21fV9f)

Comment: I am aware of the big O notation, but that is in theory.
Both algorithms have the same big O notation

Comment: I would've suggested you this https://stackoverflow.com/q/1557571/12309792 if you hadn't said that the algorithms may take up to a few days to execute completely. For you particular problem, the theoretical big o is definitely the best bet, it'll save you much time :)

Comment: Thanks for the response.
But the problem with just measuring time is that I can not tell which algorithm is faster, because they can have different CPU time.
I am looknig for a way that all of those environment variables are the same (GPU time, CPU time, RAM ...)

Comment: Okay got you. Unfortunately I'm not aware of anything like that, except for I've heard you can find the time of a script on Ubuntu or some other os. I'm not sure about that.