# How to print the time of execution PYTHON

Tags: python, time, timeit

I have this code, but I want to print the time that a specific part of it takes.
The block of code that I want to know the time is between:

```
def TSP(lista2d):
    import copy
    origen = input("Ciudad de origen: ")
    resultado = [int(origen)]
    iteracion, indicador = int(origen) - 1, 0
    distancia, copia = [], copy.deepcopy(lista2d)
    for j in range(1, len(lista2d)):
        for x in range(len(lista2d)):
            lista2d[x][iteracion] = 999
        distancia.append(min(lista2d[iteracion]))
        for i in range(len(lista2d)):
            if min(lista2d[iteracion]) == lista2d[iteracion][i]:
                indicador = i
        lista2d[indicador][iteracion] = 999
        resultado.append(indicador + 1)
        iteracion = indicador
    resultado.append(int(origen))
    a = copia[resultado[-2] - 1][int(origen) - 1]
    distancia.append(a)
    print("El camino mas corto: " + str(resultado) + "\nCosto total: " + str(sum(distancia)))

TSP([[999,100,150,140,130,120,78,150,90,200,180,190,160,135,144,300,60,77,87,90],
     [100,999,200,180,190,160,135,144,90,150,140,130,120,78,300,160,88,99,87,95],
     [150,200,999,167,156,169,123,134,156,177,155,188,176,143,192,146,170,152,176,122],
     [140,180,167,999,190,198,213,321,252,123,234,111,112,114,167,189,203,205,234,300],
     [130,190,156,190,999,333,300,178,167,143,200,111,156,267,299,152,100,90,97,99],
     [120,160,169,198,333,999,480,389,412,500,253,222,333,378,287,273,266,255,199,201],
     [78,135,123,213,300,480,999,140,150,143,177,194,166,200,181,154,177,133,122,109],
     [150,144,134,321,178,389,140,999,149,129,129,136,156,177,141,186,175,153,133,122],
     [90,90,156,252,167,412,150,149,999,89,82,83,60,124,59,78,89,99,100,123],
     [200,150,177,123,143,500,143,129,89,999,99,200,254,233,211,197,183,154,167,169],
     [180,140,155,234,200,253,177,129,82,99,999,77,88,89,289,222,311,471,122,109],
     [190,130,188,111,111,222,194,136,83,200,77,999,91,90,93,106,132,100,98,35],
     [160,120,176,112,156,333,166,156,60,254,88,91,999,102,103,107,111,113,200,101],
     [135,78,143,114,267,378,200,177,124,233,89,90,102,999,77,79,201,166,173,102],
     [144,300,192,167,299,287,181,141,59,211,289,93,103,77,999,55,103,105,101,201],
     [300,160,146,189,152,273,154,186,78,197,222,106,107,79,55,999,76,78,84,92],
     [60,88,170,203,100,266,177,175,89,183,311,132,111,201,103,76,999,93,102,29],
     [77,99,152,205,90,255,133,153,99,154,471,100,113,166,105,78,93,999,88,65],
     [87,87,176,234,97,199,122,133,100,167,122,98,200,173,101,84,102,88,999,333],
     [90,95,122,300,99,201,109,122,123,169,109,35,101,102,201,92,29,65,333,999]])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get time of a Python program's execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'time.time()' for example

```
Start_time = time.time()
End_time = time.time()
Diff_time = End_time()-Start_time()
```