# Insertion sort algorithm: which code is efficient in its structure and how come?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I made two source codes of the insertion sort algorithm.

```
def insertsort(iterable) :
    
    for current in range(len(iterable)) : # 'current' is the index of the element being sorted

        compare, n = 0,0 # Initializes 'compare' and 'n' which is used in for-loop in each current for-loop
        current_value = iterable[current] # Saves the element being sorted since the corresponding space will be assigned by the leading value
        
        for compare in range(0,current) : # Compares the element from [0] to the element right ahead of [current]            
            if iterable[compare] > iterable[current] : # Finds where to insert 'current_value,' stored value of [current]

                for n in range(current,compare,-1) : # Translate the values to one space to make the space where 'current_value' will be put empty
                    iterable[n] = iterable[n-1]
                    
                iterable[compare] = current_value # Insert the saved value of [current] to the right place
                
    return(iterable)
```

The first one is the one I made myself without any guide.

```
def insertsort(iterable) :
    for current in range(1,len(iterable)) : # iterable[0] is consdiered as resorted in the beginning
        current_value = iterable[current] # saving current value
        compare = current
        while 0 < compare and iterable[compare-1] > current_value : # finding out where to put the sorted current value
            iterable[compare] = iterable[compare-1] # this line in the while loop moves the elements not sorted
            compare -= 1 

        iterable[compare] = current_value # put current value into the right place that the while loop found out


    return(iterable)
```

The second is one I made looking at some webpages.

Comparing two, I found that the second from the internet is shorter than the one I made.

The second also demonstrated seemingly-efficient performance according to the 10-time average runtime, sorting 10000 consecutive elements (data = [i for i in range(10000, 0, -1)]

It was about 0.4 seconds faster while spending about 16 seconds to sort them all.

However, when testing with 100,000 consecutive elements(data = [i for i in range(100000, 0 ,-1)]), the first one(which I made) was faster than the second one.

The first one was about 1700 seconds, which is 200 seconds faster than the second one.

Here is my question.

1. What is the time complexity of each code? I assume both are n^2 although I'm not sure.
2. Why does the one I made seem to show better performance? I made for-loop and if-statement into while loop in the second one, but made it slower I guess.

- 

Just in case, I attach the time-measurement method that I used.
I referred to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1557584

Comment: what you mean by consecutive number? means they are already sorted?