# Python: repeat the contents of a command block in a `with` statement in a class

Tags: python, with-statement

Sorry for the possible duplication of a question. Unfortunately, I could not find an answer that is convenient for me.
I want to write a class to calculate the execution time (the mean and the rms of execution time) of a code in the manner of `%timeit` in ipython.
For this, I used this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/28218696/5328802 to use in `with` statement.

Here is the test:

```
from TimingManager import TimingManager
import numpy as np

N = 10000

def myfunction1():
    l = [i**2 for i in range(N)]
def myfunction2():
    l = np.arange(N)**2

print("List test")
with TimingManager(fun=yourfunction1,repeat=10) as t:
    t.start()

print("Array test")
with TimingManager(fun=yourfunction2, repeat=10) as t:
    t.start()
```

And here is my realisation of `TimingManager` class (file `TimingManager.py`):

```
import timeit
import statistics

class TimingManager():
    """Context Manager used with the statement 'with' to time some execution.

    Example:

    from TimingManager import TimingManager
    with TimingManager(fun=yourfunction,repeat=10) as t:
       t.start()
    """
    clock = timeit.default_timer

    def __init__(self,fun,repeat=10):
        self.repeat = repeat
        self.time_table = []
        self.run = fun

    def start(self):
        for i in range(self.repeat):
            self.timestart = self.clock()
            self.run()
            self.time_table.append(self.clock() - self.timestart)

    def __enter__(self):
        """ action on start """
        self.timestart = self.clock()

        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        """ action on exit """
        self.print_process_stat()

        return False

    def print_process_stat(self):
        tc = statistics.mean(self.time_table)
        dt = statistics.pstdev(self.time_table)
        print("Execution time is %s ± %s"%(time_conversion(tc),time_conversion(dt)))

def time_conversion(t):
    if t < 1e-9:
        return "%4.3g ps" % (t/1e-12)
    elif t < 1e-6:
        return "%4.3g ms" % (t/1e-9)
    elif t < 1e-3:
        return "%4.3g μs" % (t/1e-6)
    elif t < 1:
        return "%4.3g ms" % (t/1e-3)
    elif t < 60:
        return "%4.3g s" % (t)
    elif t < 3600:
        return "%2d min %2d s" % (t//60,t%60)
    elif t < 24*3600:
        return "%2d h %2d min" % (t//3600,(t/60)%60)
    else:
        return "%2d d %2d h" % (t//(24*3600),(t/60)%60)
```

It gives me statistics on the calculation time of what I need. But in my opinion this is not elegant. So my question is, is it possible to implement this procedure in a more elegant way (without defining the `myfunction`), namely to access the block after the `with` statement (perhaps using the content manager) to repeat it inside the `TimingManager` class? To use finally something like this:

```
with TimingManager(repeat=10):
    Statemet1
    Statemet2
    ..
```

Comment: Context managers don't get to control the `with` body. They do three things: run code on entry, run code on exit, and optionally suppress exceptions. This isn't like Ruby's `yield`.

Comment: Instead you could use a function decorator which can run the function body more than once.

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica and https://stackoverflow.com/users/388787/dan-d. But for function decoration I need to define `myfunction` again. I want to find a solution without this definition.

Comment: @AlexanderKorovin it is unclear to me how you want to avoid defining `myfunction`. This is what you want to time, no? How will you know what to time?

Comment: @Mickey, this is my question. Here I can repeat the statement block in `myfunction`, but is it possible to get the context of the with block and repeat it in the `TimingManager` class. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this, or is it possible at all.