# How to save time between presses as a variable - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make a program that counts after I press (e) and then when I press (e) again saves the time between presses, and stores that time as a variable.

Comment: Please saw your efforts first here...

Comment: use the information in this link before each input statement. Then compute the difference between the two times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution