# How can we show code execution time in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to run my python scripts but I want to see the amount of time the code takes for executing from start to end. Some like this shown in MySQL [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxaNk.png)

Thank you for your help

Comment: You can use python functions to time you code execution. Can you check ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1557584/8293176

Comment: I did check this but I thought there might be a workaround wherein VSC itself would support this requirement