# I am unable to get times in python

Tags: python, time, import, runtime-error

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution) in which, the first answer tells how to get the execution time of a program.

I have tried to implement it in my code as

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

import nod16

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

where nodo 16 is a program also generated by me. As you can tell, there are another 15 programs between `start_time` and `print`.

Unfortunately, I get the following error once I run my code:

```
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

I know this happens because I have to import another program. Unfortunately, the original post doesn't explain how to do this importing code. Can someone help?

Comment: Strange, code should work. Are you sure time is note redefined somewhere in you modules ? Maybe try to check by saving `time.time` in this script for example  `time6543236 = time.time` then call it as `time6543236()`

Comment: The code should run. That error means `time` is not imported which is not the case in your code if you run those lines on a script

Comment: importing `nod16` should not effect the time module. But let's say somehow it does. Just use `as` to import the `time` module as something else. Such as: `import time as this_is_pythons_builtin_time_module`. Then use it as: `start = this_is_pythons_builtin_time_module.time()`.

Comment: I am afraid this doestn't work `import time as tm
start_time = tm.time()
("--- %s seconds ---" % (end_time - float(start_time)))` returns ` end_time = tm.time()

 NameError: name 'tm' is not defined`