# How to add a timer to calculate my code execution

Tags: python, selenium, timer

I have written a python script which scraps products from aliexpress.

**Here is my code :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options  
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver  
from pymongo import MongoClient
from time import sleep
from lxml import html 
import pandas as pd
import cssselect
import pymongo
import json 
import csv 


options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r"C:\Users\aicha\Desktop\mycode\aliexpress_scrap\scrap\codes\msedgedriver",options=options)
url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?trafficChannel=main&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=bluetooth+earphones&ltype=wholesale&SortType=default&page={}'
baseurl = 'https://www.aliexpress.com'

for page_nb in range(1, 2):
    print('---', page_nb, '---')
    
    driver.get(url.format(page_nb))
    sleep(2)
    current_offset = 0
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);")
        sleep(.5)  # JavaScript has time to add elements
        new_offset = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
        print(new_offset,current_offset)
        if new_offset <= current_offset:
            break
        current_offset = new_offset
    
    sleep(3)
    
    tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
    
    results = []
    
    for product in tree.xpath('//div[@class="JIIxO"]//a'):
        title = product.xpath('.//h1/text()')
        
        if title:
            title = title[0]
            
            price = product.cssselect('div.mGXnE._37W_B span')
            price = [x.text for x in price]

            currency = price[0]
            price = ''.join(price[1:])
            stars = product.xpath('.//span[@class="eXPaM"]/text()')
            if stars :
                stars  = stars [0]
            else:
                stars  = 'None'
                
            nb_sold = product.xpath('.//span[@class="_1kNf9"]/text()')
            if nb_sold:
                nb_sold = nb_sold[0]
            else:
                nb_sold = 'None'
            supl = product.xpath('.//a[@class="ox0KZ"]/text()')
            if supl:
                supl = supl[0]
            else:
                supl = 'None'

            ship_cost = product.xpath('.//span[@class="_2jcMA"]/text()')
            if ship_cost:
                ship_cost = ship_cost[0]
            else:
                ship_cost = 'None'
            
            product_links = product.xpath('./@href')
            if product_links:
                product_links = str(baseurl) + str( product_links[0])
            
            row = [title, price, currency, stars, nb_sold, ship_cost, supl, product_links]
            results.append(row)
            print('len(results):', len(results))

    driver.close()
df = pd.DataFrame(results , columns=("Title","Price", "Currency", "Stars", "Orders", "Shipcost", "Supplier", "Productlinks" ))

####### Insert in database #############
client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")     
collection = client['db2']['aliex2']     
data = df.to_dict(orient = 'records')     
collection.insert_many(data)
```

**My question :**

What I need is to add a timer that calculate the time of process and returns a value to know how much time takes the code.
And also I want a method in order ro get a new collection after each scraping because when I run my code the second time, I get my data with the old collection.

I appreciate any help from you . Thank you !

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get time of a Python program's execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May your problem solve in below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options  
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver  
from pymongo import MongoClient
from time import sleep
from lxml import html 
import pandas as pd
import cssselect
import pymongo
import json 
import csv 
import time as Time


options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r"C:\Users\aicha\Desktop\mycode\aliexpress_scrap\scrap\codes\msedgedriver",options=options)
url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?trafficChannel=main&d=y&CatId=0&SearchText=bluetooth+earphones&ltype=wholesale&SortType=default&page={}'
baseurl = 'https://www.aliexpress.com'

for page_nb in range(1, 2):
    print('---', page_nb, '---')
    
    driver.get(url.format(page_nb))
    sleep(2)
    current_offset = 0
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);")
        sleep(.5)  # JavaScript has time to add elements
        new_offset = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
        print(new_offset,current_offset)
        if new_offset <= current_offset:
            break
        current_offset = new_offset
    
    sleep(3)
    
    tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
    
    results = []
    
    for product in tree.xpath('//div[@class="JIIxO"]//a'):
        start_time = Time.time()
        title = product.xpath('.//h1/text()')
        
        if title:
            title = title[0]
            
            price = product.cssselect('div.mGXnE._37W_B span')
            price = [x.text for x in price]

            currency = price[0]
            price = ''.join(price[1:])
            stars = product.xpath('.//span[@class="eXPaM"]/text()')
            if stars :
                stars  = stars [0]
            else:
                stars  = 'None'
                
            nb_sold = product.xpath('.//span[@class="_1kNf9"]/text()')
            if nb_sold:
                nb_sold = nb_sold[0]
            else:
                nb_sold = 'None'
            supl = product.xpath('.//a[@class="ox0KZ"]/text()')
            if supl:
                supl = supl[0]
            else:
                supl = 'None'

            ship_cost = product.xpath('.//span[@class="_2jcMA"]/text()')
            if ship_cost:
                ship_cost = ship_cost[0]
            else:
                ship_cost = 'None'
            
            product_links = product.xpath('./@href')
            if product_links:
                product_links = str(baseurl) + str( product_links[0])
            difference_time = Time.time() - start_time # calculate time taken by program
            
            row = [title, price, currency, stars, nb_sold, ship_cost, supl, product_links, difference_time] #difference_time store dataframe
            results.append(row)
            print('len(results):', len(results))

    driver.close()
df = pd.DataFrame(results , columns=("Title","Price", "Currency", "Stars", "Orders", "Shipcost", "Supplier", "Productlinks", "Time Taken"))

####### Insert in database #############
client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")     
collection = client['db2']['aliex2']     
data = df.to_dict(orient = 'records')     
collection.insert_many(data)
```

I had find out time taken by program in loop and store that difference time in dataframe

Comment: Actually it works, but I want to print how much time in my terminal not in my database

Comment: what do you mean by terminal?

Comment: From where you want to check time write this code:`start_time = Time.time()` and at last you can find difference time using `diffrence_time = Time.time() - start_time`

Comment: Thank you it works for this question. But I need also a method to create new collection after every execution code

Comment: Glad to help youplease create a new question for other problem I will surely help you

Comment: It is already in my question

Comment: But I can not understand your second requirement what you want as output? all scrap data and time is stored as dataframe is it not ok?

Comment: I want after each execution to store data in a new collection because when I execute the code for the second time, I get the data in the same collection.

Comment: Is it fix or dynamic that how many time you will execute the code?

Comment: No they are two seperated questions.

Comment: so please create a new question with all information and requirement If you need Help

Comment: Here is the link of my question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71870535/how-to-create-new-collection-datatabase-after-each-scraping-execution.  I would be grateful for any help

Comment: I think your question is solved by the answer of @Leon Menkreo.I will be gratefully if you need any more help.

Comment: No it is still need help because I don't know how to edit my django view

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can utilize a time library.

```py
import time
#Beginning of your code
timeStart = time.time()
....
....
....
print("%s seconds elapsed " % (time.time() - timeStart))

#End of your code
```

At the beginning, you should obtain the current time and assign it to a variable. After that, subtract it from the current time at the end of your code.