# How to check runtime of each function within a task in Airflow DAG?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a simple DAG which goes like this:

start >> create_cluster >> **run_code** >> delete_cluster >> end

The run_code runs a python script which is stored in Google Cloud Storage. This python script runs multiple functions to produce the output.

I would like to know if the runtime of these functions can be fetched.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the `PythonOperator` for the `run_code` task:

For your `run_code` task's function, you can simply add the following:

```
import time

def run_code_function():
    # Starting the function.
    start_time = time.time() 

    # Business Code Logic...

    # You can log it as well
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    return important_stuff
```

To investigate more about it, [check here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1557584/10618163)

Printing these values will give you the result at the log file where you initialized your DAG.