# Faster way to find all columns are with no missing values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, missing-data

Currently I am using this statement to find all columns in a dataframe that *has no missing* values, it works fine.  but I'm wondering if there is more concise way (albeit, efficient way) to do the same thing?

```
df.columns[ np.sum(df.isnull()) == 0 ]
```

Comment: provide sample dataframe and desired output as well

Comment: The expected outputs will be just those columns names only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To better answer the question one would need to have access to the dataframe in question.

Without it, there are various method one can use.

Let's consider the following dataframe as example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.iloc[0:10, 0] = np.nan

[Out]:
    A   B   C   D
0 NaN  89  63  41
1 NaN  12  47   8
2 NaN  79  76  67
3 NaN  87  61  38
4 NaN  28  31  30
```

1. Method 1 - As OP indicated (we will be use as reference)

   ```
   df.columns[ np.sum(df.isnull()) == 0 ]
   ```
2. Method 2 - Similar to Method 1, with [`numpy.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) and [`pandas.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html), but with a Lambda function

   ```
   df.columns[ df.apply(lambda x: np.sum(x.isnull()) == 0) ]
   ```
3. Method 3 - Using [`numpy.all`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html)

   ```
   columns = df.columns[ np.all(df.notnull(), axis=0) ]
   ```
4. Method 4 - Using only pandas built-in modules

   ```
   columns = df.columns[ df.isnull().sum() == 0 ]
   ```
5. Method 5 - Using [`pandas.DataFrame.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html)
   (same method [used here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73778982/7109869)).

   ```
   columns = df.columns[ df.isna().any() == False ]
   ```

The output in all is [the one that OP wants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73778886/faster-way-to-find-all-columns-are-with-no-missing-values/73779175?noredirect=1#comment130278817_73778886), more specifically

```
Index(['B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

If one times each of the methods with [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) (there are [additional ways to measure the time of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1557571/7109869)), one will get the following

```
     method          time
0  method 1  2.999996e-07
1  method 2  3.000005e-07
2  method 3  2.000006e-07
3  method 4  6.000000e-07
4  method 5  3.999994e-07
```

[image]

Again, this might change depending on the dataframe that one uses. Also, depending on the requirements (hardware, and business requirements), there might be other ways to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for the detail analysis... So it seems the original approach is good enough.

Comment: @DanielHao there are even more ways to achieve what you are looking for. The best results would depend on the type of data at hand, so, to give a better answer, one would need access to the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
df.isna().any() # returns all columns either True (column names that has MISSING values) False (column names has NO MISSING values)

df.columns[df.isna().any()]  # returns only the column names with MISSING values

df.columns[~df.isna().any()] # tilda negates the condition # returns the columns with NO MISSING values

df.columns[~df.isna().any()].tolist() # .tolist() converts the result to a list, if you wish.
```

Comment: @Daniel Hao you can add this piece of code at the end, if you wish to convert the results to a list `.tolist()`

Comment: Yeah, this is another way to achieve it.  +1 (upvote it)

Comment: Glad it worked for you, i was puzzled how it did not work for you the first time

Comment: The explanation could be more precise - #2 case.  "Only the columns *without* any missing values...."

Comment: You still miss it - *without*  not *with*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248181/discussion-between-daniel-hao-and-echo).