# Execution time is varying every time I run the python program. Is there any way to solve this?

Tags: python, time, runtime

I am running a program in Google Colab. I am using `time` module to compute the time of execution like `start=time.time();....end=time.time()`.
Every time I run the code it's execution time is varying.

Is there a way I can find the `average execution time` or `some other function` I can use to resolve this.

I am running the same code using *Linux Terminal*. So
It is appreciated even if I can find the average time of execution while running the python program from *Linux Terminal*.

Comment: Yes there is. Don't use Google Colab

Comment: Then how to get it using _Linux Terminal_

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to this problem.

1. If you want to test a function or piece of code, you can write a script that does your own calculations with the help of a decorator.
2. you can make use of existing libraries.

I think there are enough examples for both options in the following title; [How do I get time of a Python program's execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution)

If there is something you cannot do specifically other than these, if you write, I can help.

Comment: I believe these solutions also give variable time. Have you tested with any code?

Comment: These solutions test and average the code snippet you write over and over.  It depends on the code you wrote.  And yes, for example, I saw average differences in random tests I did for migrations and sql queries.