# How to remove the last character of a string and return removed one?

Tags: python, string

If I have a string:

```
s = 'abcadlfog'
```

I want to remove the last character from it but I should get that last one saved to another variable.

```
result = s[:-1]
```

I tried this but it only returns copy of the new string.

Comment: Can you tell also runtime of it? pls, also tell runtime of it takes to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown above, you can also use the s.rpartition method, but I think slicing looks better to the eye.

```py
s = 'abcadlfog'
result, last = s[:-1], s[-1]

print(first, last)
```

Also, there is no noticeable difference in performance between the two codes. The choice is yours.

```py
>>> %timeit result, last, _ = s.rpartition(s[-1])
53.3 ns ± 0.262 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)

>>> %timeit result, last = s[:-1], s[-1]
52.7 ns ± 0.392 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use unpacking syntax.

```
>>> s = 'abcadlfog'
>>> *first, last = s
>>> "".join(first)
'abcadlfo'
>>> last
'g'
```

Comment: Can you tell also runtime of it? pls

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) string method:

```py
s = 'abcadlfog'
result, last, _ = s.rpartition(s[-1])

print(result, last, sep='\n')
```

Gives:

```
abcadlfo
g
```

Comment: Can you tell also runtime of it? pls

Comment: @AbdulazizAbduhakimov [How do I get time of a Python program's execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1557571/6045800)