# Get function passed as an argument name inside another function

Tags: python, function

I am trying to measure elapse time for different functions with simple method like this:

```
def taketime(executable,exname='method'):
    tic = time.time()
    exname = executable.__name__
    out = executable
    toc = time.time()
    print('Time taken for ',exname,' ',toc-tic,' sec')
    return out
```

Executable is another method, can be whatever. Nevertheless, the program does not work as the line `exname = executable.__name__` is actually already running executable and trying to get the property **name** from the output.

What is the correct way to get the name of the executable passed to another function?

Small test program (not working):

```
import time
def taketime(executable,exname=None):
    tic = time.time()
    if exname is None: exname = executable.__name__
    out = executable
    toc = time.time()
    print('Time taken for ',exname,' ',toc-tic,' sec')
    return out
# -----------------------------------------
def hello():
    print('Hello!')
    return
dd = taketime(hello())
```

Of course it works when I do this:
`dd = taketime(hello(),'hello')`

Comment: did you mean to run `dd = taketime(hello)` ? adding the extra `()` parenthesis calls the function when you just want to pass it as an argument

Comment: Idea is to call the function and see how much time it took...

Comment: Even then you need to pass it as an argument and **not** call it. But if your aim is just to check performance time, then explore  this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557571/how-do-i-get-time-of-a-python-programs-execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the target function before it is passed into your `taketime()` function. Also, you don't call anything inside your function either. You meant to write your code like this:

```py
import time
def taketime(executable, *args, **kwargs):
    exname = executable.__name__
    tic = time.time()
    out = executable(*args, **kwargs)
    toc = time.time()
    print('Time taken for ',exname,' ',toc-tic,' sec')
    return out
# -----------------------------------------
def hello():
    print('Hello!')
    return
dd = taketime(hello)
```

Note that:

1. the call to `taketime` is like this: `taketime(hello)`
2. the target function is actually called like this: `out = executable()`
3. supply extra arguments like this: `taketime(hello, arg1, arg2)`

Comment: Yeah, but usually I have complicated functions with input. So, `hello()` is actually `hello(arg1,arg2,arg3)`... Therefore I put it as `dd = taketime(hello())` as I can have `dd = taketime(hello(arg1,arg2,arg3))`...

Comment: Easily handled. I'll update my answer . . .

Comment: Works like a charm!