# Using the windows command line can I time a process that I am running?

Tags: time, cmd

I am running a process on a windows command line, it is going to take a long time (30+ hours) and I want to know how long it takes to complete. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can find a more complete answer on Stack Overflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use PowerShell you can use [`measure-command`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347702.aspx).

Otherwise just grab something that echos the current date/time to stdout and call that before and after (maybe redirecting to append to a file with `>>`).