# Measure execution time in minutes and seconds

Tags: powershell

I would like to measure multiple times in an automation PowerShell script. I used Get-Date and TotalSeconds. The result looks for example like this: 236.908

How can I get the elapsed time as human readable in minutes and seconds?

```
$startTime = (Get-Date)
$endTime = (Get-Date)

$ElapsedTime = (($endTime-$startTime).TotalSeconds)

Write-Host "Duration: xx min xx sec"
```

Comment: `($endTime-$startTime).ToString('''Duration: ''mm'' min ''ss'' sec''')`

Comment: @PetSerAl Hi, why the quote frenzy?

Comment: Works! Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a better timer output in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811947/get-a-better-timer-output-in-powershell)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`):

```
'Duration: {0:mm} min {0:ss} sec' -f ($endTime-$startTime)
```

or like this, if you need the difference elsewhere as well:

```
$ElapsedTime = $endTime-$startTime
'Duration: {0:mm} min {0:ss} sec' -f $ElapsedTime
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Measure-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Measure-Command) too:

```
Measure-Command -Expression {

    # Command 1
    Get-ChildItem

    # Command N
    Get-Process
}
```

Or like this:

```
$result = Measure-Command -Expression {

    # Command 1
    Get-ChildItem

    # Command N
    Get-Process
}

$result.ToString()
```