# Using the Get-Date cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I am taking a scripting class as part of my IT degree and I am stumped on my powershell script.  I have to use `Get-Date` to time how long my game is played, and also create a log file that stores number of games played, and the shorted and longest games played. The log file must be created outside the script, but must update within the script. I put the code I have so far below.

```
$rand = new-object system.random
$number= $rand.next(0,11)
clear-host

do{ $a = read-host -prompt "enter number between 1 and 10"
if ($a -gt $Number) {Write-Host "number is too high"}
elseif ($a -lt $Number) {Write-Host "number is too low"}
elseif ($a -eq $Number) {Write-Host "You did it!! It took you $x tries!"}
else {"You have to guess a number!!!"}
$x = $x + 1
 } while ($a -ne $number)
$path = C:\temp\logfile.log.txt
```

Comment: Do you have a question? What is your issue? SO is not a homework help site.

Comment: I am aware this is not for getting homework help.  My question is:  how to you use get-date as a timer to find out the length of game played.  is it just get-date.timeofday - get-date.timeofday?

Comment: See this question for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3513650/775544

Answer (score 0):

To time execution, grab the date *before* and *after* you've done your work, and then subtract the two to get a `TimeSpan` representing the time it took

```
$StartTime = Get-Date
# script goes here
$EndTime   = Get-Date
$TimeTaken = $EndTime - $StartTime
Write-Host "A total of $($TimeTaken.TotalSeconds) has passed"
```

You could also use the `StopWatch` class to accomplish this:

```
$Watch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
# script goes here
$Watch.Stop()
$TimeTaken = $Watch.Elapsed
Write-Host "A total of $($TimeTaken.TotalSeconds) has passed"
```