# BATCH - Move files older than 5 minutes

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a move executable files with more than 5 minutes. Do not know how to compare the modified date of the file VS the system date.

```
@echo off

for %%f in (*.log) do ( 

move %%~nf.log \Procesados

)

exit
```

Comment: Does it *have* to be in Batch? This would be massively easier in Powershell!

Comment: there might be something in this post for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922498/calculate-time-difference-in-batch-file

Comment: When I set the date modified for the file, e.g set filetime=%%~tf the variable filetime is empty, I can't compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to download  [findutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm)  and [coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) then do this:

```
gnu_find . -type f -mmin +05 -exec cp "{}" c:\destination ;
```

that's all you need. Date calculation is taken care of as well. No need to reinvent your own date calculation.

**EDIT As per OP queries:**

In below example FIND searches for all the files in current directory (.)

```
gnu_find . -type f -mmin +5 -exec cp "{}" C:\destination\folder ;
```

But, you can specify a directory to search as you wish:

```
gnu_find D:\source\folder -type f -mmin +5 -exec cp "{}" E:\destination\folder ;
```

**To learn more options of FIND utility, read here.....**

[Read me-1](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)

[Read me-2](http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/unix/findcmd.htm)

[Read me-3](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html)

Comment: If I want to move the files from the source directory to the target directory, as should be the command?

Answer (score 0):

This batch will keep running untill you stop it and if it finds a file is older than Xtime it moves it to a destination.
Put the batch in the same folder with the .log files.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:Loop
set "Xtime=5"

For /F "tokens=2,* delims=:" %%a in ('echo %time%') Do set CurrTime=%%a
For %%a in (*.log) Do (
For /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%b in ("%%~ta") Do (
set "Ftime=%%b"
set /a check = CurrTime - Ftime
IF !check! GEQ !Xtime! ( MOVE /Y %%~fsa path_to_destiantion_folder
) Else ( goto next )
)
)

:next
goto Loop
```

change the Xtime to suit your needs.

[CURTSEY: This thread](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3602)

Comment: It looks like this will fail depending on the time format.  24 vs 12 hour time.