# Deleting Items in a folder after a certain age

Tags: windows

Wanting to know what language you would recommend. Have been talking to some friends and they recommended against CMD.

Basically I want to check %SystemRoot%\SYSTEM32\SPOOL\PRINTERS and see if there is any files older than 30 seconds or 1 minute. The physical number will be set. Then if it is delete the file.

If some one could guide me in the best way to program this that would be great :)

Comment: You can use batch script for your above purpose. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785216/batch-script-to-delete-files-older-than-x-days-based-on-creation-date-not-modi

Comment: create a batch file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887130/batch-move-files-older-than-5-minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell is your friend. Part of your description is a little bit unclear, but here is what a script doing what I understand you want would resemble:

```
dir $env:SystemRoot\SYSTEM32\SPOOL\PRINTERS | 
where { ((get-date)-$_.creationTime).seconds -gt 30 } |
remove-item -force
```

Comment: Looks great. I am no wiz kid at PowerShell. What is the easiest way to get this to loop constantly? Just had a quick google of it and there are a few ways of doing it, though apparently you have to be careful of spirals