# Multiple Variables - Generator

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, dos

I'm trying to create a 1 line code where it adds up all variables its hard to explain in text right but here's a small part of the code

```
H = hours
M = Minutes
Thr = Total Hours
Tmin= Total Minutes

Call data.bat 
Rem data.bat is all the h1,m1,h2,m2,h3,m3... info

Rem Example Data
H1=3
M1=53
H2=4
M2=20
Set num=1
:refresh
if %H%num%% GTR 0 set /a Thr=%H%num%%+%Thr%
if %M%num%% GTR 0 set /a Thr=%M%num%%+%TMin%
if %M%num%% EQU 0 Goto :total
set /a number=%number%+1
goto :refresh
:Total
set /a Total=((%Thr%*60)+%Tmin%)
set /a TotalHour=(%Total%/60)
set /a TotalMin=(-%TotalHour%*60)+%Total%
if %Totalmin% GEQ 0 if %Totalmin% LEQ 9 set Totalmin=0%Totalmin%
Echo Duration    : %TotalHour%hr %TotalMin%min
```

Hours does not have if 0 goto total because there may be times where there was 0 hours but ##'s minutes
Any Ideas on how to do this?
Running it as is gives me

step by step operation

```
if %h%num%% gtr 0 set /a Thr=%h%num%%+%thr%
If %h1% gtr 0 set /a thr=%h1%+%thr%
If 3 gtr 0 set /a thr=**3+%thr%
if 3 gtr 0 set /a thr=3+1
```

Comment: if you trying to set 1 var with values of 2 other vars or show 2 vars, write it with the correct number of `%`. ie. `if %H%%num% ...` and `set /a Thr=%H%%num%+%Thr%` instead. each vars inside 2 `%`.

Comment: if `Thr=2 H3=4 Num=3` then I want a way so I could change `if %H%num%% GTR 0 set /a Thr=%H%num%%+%Thr%` so it reads `If  4 GTR 0 set /a THR=4+2`

Comment: @Paul: The OP is not trying to set 1 var with values of 2 other vars nor show 2 vars, but access one _array element_: `set /a Thr=!H%num%!+%Thr%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several points in your code that needs to be adjusted:

- The rigth way to access *array elements* via an *index* is using Delayed Expansion, as fully explained at [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990):

.

```
if !H%num%! GTR 0 set /a Thr=!H%num%!+%Thr%
```

- However, the `set /a` command can directly access array elements when just the name of the variable is given, so *in this case* it is not necesssary to expand the value:

.

```
set /a Thr=H%num%+Thr
set /a number=number+1
```

The last line may also be written this way:

```
set /a number+=1
```

- If you want to check if a variable does not exist (and not confuse it with a variable with zero value), you may use `if defined` command:

.

```
if defined H%num% goto refresh
```

- You used the wrong variable name a couple of times: `number` instead of `num`, and `Thr` in the *minutes* calculation.

.

This is the final code after completed previous modifications:

```
@echo off

REM H = hours
REM M = Minutes
REM Thr = Total Hours
REM Tmin= Total Minutes

REM Call data.bat 
Rem data.bat is all the h1,m1,h2,m2,h3,m3... info

Rem Example Data
set H1=3
set M1=53
set H2=4
set M2=20
Set num=1
:refresh
set /a Thr=H%num%+Thr
set /a Tmin=M%num%+Tmin
set /a num=num+1
if defined M%num% Goto :refresh
:Total
set /a Total=((Thr*60)+Tmin)
set /a TotalHour=(Total/60)
set /a TotalMin=(-TotalHour*60)+Total
if %Totalmin% LEQ 9 set Totalmin=0%Totalmin%
Echo Duration    : %TotalHour%hr %TotalMin%min
```

Output:

```
Duration    : 8hr 13min
```

Comment: Don't have enough Rep right now but +1 I know it says not to but +2

Answer (score 2):

you Need delayed Expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set h1=3
set x=1
echo !h%x%!
```

**EDIT** to Show how it works with the example in your comment:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Thr=2
set H3=4
set Num=3
    REM echo if !H%Num%! GTR 0 set /a Thr=!H%num%!+%Thr%
    echo if !H%Num%! GTR 0 set /a Thr+=!H%num%!
    REM if !H%Num%! GTR 0 set /a Thr=!H%num%!+%Thr%
if !H%Num%! GTR 0 set /a Thr+=!H%num%!
echo %Thr%
```

(note: the intended lines are redundant, just to display, what happens)
I used a different syntax to add a value to a variable; Commented out your syntax. Both versions are working the same.

```
%h%num%%
```

will be interpreted as (inserted underscores to Show, how the Parser groups it):

```
%h%_num_%%
```

with `%h%`(probably) undefined (shown below as ~), `%%` interpreded as an escaped single literal `%`, resulting in:

```
~_num_%
```

or without the placeholders:

```
num%
```

The same with delayed Expansion:

```
!H%Num%!
```

`%num%`being 3:

```
!H3!
```

which is getting expanded to:

```
4
```

User **jeb** wrote a great answer to [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/2152082) (hard stuff, but helps to understand, what's going on)

Comment: I want to so `if Thr=2 H3=4 Num=3` then I want a way so I could change `if %H%num%% GTR 0 set /a Thr=%H%num%%+%Thr%` so it reads If `4 GTR 0 set /a THR=4+2`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking a formula to parse time and calculate duration, you might look this: [Calculate Time difference in Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17217171)

Comment: its time, but the conversion from hh:mm:ss.ms is already done just need to find a way to make %h%num%% to = %h1% which equals a number

Comment: The question is not about Time difference, but precisely the opposite thing: add several times...