# Bat file for start and exit time

Tags: batch-file, time, download, exe

I have a **.exe** file to download data from a chip. 
I want to know the **start time** and the **exit time** of this program, using a .bat file, but I have no idea how to do this.

Please help me!

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to measure execution time of command in windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case yourexecutable scrolls / pages start time out of screen I'd prefer:

```
Set StartTime=%time%
ECHO start: %StartTime%
yourexecutable
Set EndTime=%time%
Echo start: %StartTime%
Echo end  : %EndTime%
Echo Yourexecutable ran form %StartTime% to %EndTime% >>"YourExe.Log"
Pause
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! If I want to save a print of the time in a file .txt , and maybe also the difference between the start_time and the end_time, how can I do? Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: I added logging to the above batch, for the time difference there are already [Q&A for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922498/calculate-time-difference-in-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 3):

```
ECHO start: %time%
yourexecutable
echo end  : %time%
```

is the way I'd do it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
If I want to save a print of the time in a file .txt , and maybe also the difference between the start_time and the end_time, how can I do? Is it possible?
Thanks