# Get the difference between current date and a previous date

Tags: date, batch-file, cmd

If I enter `echo %date%` in cmd I will get the date it is today. Let us say that today is `Wednesday, 21/11/2018`. If I type `echo %date%` cmd will print `Wed 11/21/2018`. Yesterday, it would have returned `Tue 11/20/2018`. The difference between these two dates (in days) is `1`.

Is there any way I can do this kind of subtraction in command prompt? Something like:

```
set previous_date=Tue 11/20/2018
echo %date% - %previous_date%
```

I know this should be very easy to do in a programming language like `python` or `VBScript`, but I don't want to use any of those, unless it is absolutely necessary. I can download and use custom command line tools, but I want to do this with a batch file.

Anyone who knows how?

Comment: Is there any maximum number of days? Or it could be any number?

Comment: @Aacini any number. Even if you don't have the complete answer, just an idea on how this might be done, please share. You might point me in the right direction.

Comment: It is relatively simple to get a difference when both dates are separated by a max of one month. Otherwise the method is more complex... I will post a partial answer soon.

Comment: @Aacini thanks waiting

Comment: @Aacini since you are involved I might as well tell you why I need this. I have a bat file in my Startup folder that runs a process once a week. It does this by checking the current day and running the process if its monday `if %date:~0,1%==M ()`. Problem is I need this process to launch `AT LEAST` once every 7 days. But if say I forget to open my laptop on a particular monday this it doesn't launch the process until the next monday. So now I simply want to change the logic to `launch the process if it hasn't been launched for at least 7 days`. regardless of what day it is.

Comment: Now you might be wondering how do I even fetch the previous date. I mean you can't connect a bat file to a database can you? Well I did manage to discover a clever way to do this without any database. Will tell you if you wanna know. This question is the only missing piece in the logic.

Comment: Batch scripting is not well suited for date maths, because there is actually no such data type; you could however borrow from other languages, like PowerShell, JavaScript, VBScript, for instance, and do the difference computation there; in pure batch programming, you had to implement it on your own, handling locale-dependent date formats, leap years, etc....

Comment: Related: [Date time difference in batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47532900).

Comment: @aschipfl I do want to "implement it on my own". I am not here for the answer so much as I am here for the right direction.

Comment: I suggest thr following: When your job actually runs (i.e. when the 7-day condition is met), create or update a file by running something like `echo 1 >"c:\some\file.txt"`. Then to test if it is time to run again by using `robocopy /minage:7 "c:\some\file.txt" "c:\some\test.txt"`. This will only copy the file if it is at least 7 days old. Check if it exists with `if exist "c:\some\test.txt" goto TIME_HAS_COME`. Don't forget to `del /y "c:\some\test.txt"` afterwards.

Comment: @JackWhite that might be it thanks

Comment: @JackWhite your solution works!

Comment: @aschipfl please unmark this question as duplicate. I got the answer which is nothing like the question with which you have marked MY question as duplicate.

Comment: Also related: [Calculate time difference in Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9922498).

Comment: @AsifAli, I unmarked it, because the linked question is about time but not date difference (although it is almost the same). Anyway, I am curious about your solution...

Comment: @aschipfl thanks for understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I have previously posted this in the comments because the question was locked. Since it is now unlocked I am submitting this as an answer)

Batch scripting language does not have any built-in means to calculate time difference. This problem may be solved through various means such as:

- Write it using other scripting languages such as VBS, AutoIt, PowerShell, etc.
- Download existing external program such as unix `date` utility from [gnuwin32 coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) ([manual](https://ss64.com/bash/date.html), [recipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/quickly-calculate-date-differences)). Use `for` to get output of `date "+%%s"` into a variable, then use `set /a` to calculate the difference.
- Parse output from built-in `date` command or `%date%` variable. This is discussed in great detail elsewhere ([A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922498/calculate-time-difference-in-windows-batch-file), [B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47532900/date-time-difference-in-batch-script), [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385030/batch-timestamp-to-unix-time), [D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192476/format-date-and-time-in-a-windows-batch-script), [E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859703/how-to-format-date-in-batch-file)) but be aware that it may be affected by OS locale time/date representation, and it is also hard to take leap years into account properly if you need precision.

I'd like to share another trick: using file creation date difference. It is still a somewhat of a hack, but is arguably more portable than parsing `%date%` by hand.

Here is an example, explanation below:

```
if not exist "c:\some\marker.txt" goto RunTheJob
robocopy /minage:7 "c:\some\marker.txt" "c:\some\test.txt"
if exist "c:\some\test.txt" goto RunTheJob
goto SkipTheJob

:RunTheJob
del /y "c:\some\test.txt"
echo 1 >"c:\some\marker.txt"
rem ... THIS RUNS ONCE IN 7 DAYS ...

:SkipTheJob
```

Whenever we run the job (i.e. once in 7 days) we also create (or update) a "marker" file (`c:\some\marker.txt` in the example). Contents and location of this file do not matter, only date of its modification does, so I just write character `1` into it with `echo 1 >YOUR_FILENAME`

This also neatly solves the problem of storing date information somewhere.

Now to test if at least 7 days passed since the job last ran you need to check if the file is at least 7 days old. Easiest way is with `robocopy` utility - its `/minage:NNN` parameter only copies the file if it is at least NNN days old.

So we periodically try to copy the file and see if it succeeds. We do this by checking if copied file (`c:\some\test.txt`) exists like this: `if exist YOUR_FILENAME goto YOUR_LABEL`

Finally, if the file was copied it is no longer needed and we need to delete it with `del /y YOUR_FILENAME`. `/y` overrides confirmations just in case and may normally be omitted.

If the marker file is ever deleted for any reason, the first line in the example makes sure that job (I'm assuming some kind of backup or something like that) is started right away. If it wasn't there, the file would never be copied because the original would not exist in the first place, so the job would never run in this situation.

Quirks:

If some program updates the modification date of a "marker" file for some reason, the job will be delayed. If this is undesired you should put this file somewhere out of reach, such as `%AppData%\Roaming\YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME` folder. Same thing may happen if the file gets restored from a backup.

To work around such a problem you may consider compressing the marker file into an archive such as `zip`, but this also requires external programs, VBS or PowerShell. It might be possible to somehow abuse built-in Windows Backup utility (`sdclt`) instead but I have not found a way.

Comment: thanks for the detailed info. Thanks to you I got what I wanted when I posted my question on stackoverflow. File age! so simple, yet genius.

Answer (score 3):

In one of your comments you say:

> I have a bat file in my Startup folder that runs a process once a
>   week. It does this by checking the current day and running the process
>   if its monday if %date:~0,1%==M (). Problem is I need this process to
>   launch AT LEAST once every 7 days. But if say I forget to open my
>   laptop on a particular monday this it doesn't launch the process until
>   the next monday. So now I simply want to change the logic to launch
>   the process if it hasn't been launched for at least 7 days

That's what TaskScheduler is built to take care of. No need to mess with date calculations or even language dependend formats of `%date%`.

Start TaskScheduler
"Create Task"  (do not "Create Basic Task")
in "Triggers" set to "Weekly", "Recure every `1` weeks on: `Monday`
in "Settings" check "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed"
Fill also the "General", "Actions" and "Conditions" tabs to your needs.

Comment: thanks for your answer, although I used Jack White's way of doing it, yours probably also works. Hopefully it will help someone else reading this question in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem as Asif ALi, but neither Task Scheduler nor robocopy worked for me.

Task Scheduler cannot shedula a task for running at logon AND once in 7 days. Either is possible, but both don't.

Robocopy interprets my file names as folders, therefore doesn't find them. I used the same syntax as Jack suggested.

```
robocopy /minage:7 "D:\Backups\Browsers\lastbackup.txt" "D:\Backups\Browsers\datest.txt"
```

result :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Mon Jun 13 02:09:01 2022

   Source : D:\Backups\Browsers\lastbackup.txt\
     Dest : D:\Backups\Browsers\datest.txt\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /COPY:DAT /MINAGE:7 /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2022/06/13 02:09:01 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Source Directory D:\Backups
\Browsers\lastbackup.txt\
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Could Not Find d:\Backups\Browsers\datest.txt
```

I have Windows 7 Ultimate x64.
Printed out robocopy /? but didn't find the right syntax.

---

UPDATE 2022.06.14. 16:41 :

I successfully managed to make use of robocopy this way :

```
set testfolder=datest_%date%
rem timeout 10
cd D:\Backups\Browsers\
if not exist lastbackup.txt goto dobackup
robocopy /minage:7 "D:\Backups\Browsers" "%testfolder%" lastbackup.txt
if not exist %testfolder%\lastbackup.txt goto end

:dobackup
echo.
echo Starting backup process
...
echo %date% >> lastbackup.txt

:end
rd /s /q %testfolder%
rem echo That's all folks ...
```

Comment: Er, well - this is not an answer to the question, but a new question since this existing question didn't solve your problem. Please post it as a new question so that it can be responded to in its own right, probably referencing this question, but clearly stating your goals. Your response will no doubt be deleted because it is not an answer. This is the normal fate on SO of this class of response.