# Batch counts how many seconds it's been run

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a batch script that counts how long it's been run in seconds. How can I do this?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you actually trying to accomplish by determining how long the script has been running?

Comment: See: [Calculate time difference in Windows Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922498/calculate-time-difference-in-windows-batch-file/9935540#9935540)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you would like it. >u<

---

Add this into the first line of the batch that you wanted to count its running time:

`echo %time% >"starting time.any-file-type"`

And that into the end(s) of the batch file:

`(start) "counter.bat"`

---

> Code of "counter.bat"

```
@echo off
set thetimenow=%time%
set /p thetimebefore=<"starting time.any-file-type"
set /a hours=%thetimenow:~0,2% - %thetimebefore:~0,2%
set /a mins=%thetimenow:~3,2% - %thetimebefore:~3,2%
set /a seconds=%thetimenow:~6,2% - %thetimebefore:~6,2%
set /a minsecs=%thetimenow:~9,2% - %thetimebefore:~9,2%
if %minsecs% lss 0 (set /a seconds-=1
set /a minsecs+=100)
if %seconds% lss 0 (set /a mins-=1
set /a seconds+=60)
if %mins% lss 0 (set /a hours-=1
set /a mins+=60)
if %hours% lss 0 (set /a days=1
set /a hours+=24)
if not "%days%" == "1" (set days=) else (set days=1 or more days, )
echo The batch required has ran for %days%%hours% hour(s), %mins% minute(s), %seconds% second(s), and %minsecs% miniseconds.
```

---

That's the best that I can give.

Note that the required batch must NOT contain the keyword `exit`.

If needed, use `chcp 437` right before the line which contains `%time%`.

Make sure the batches are at the same folder if you don't wish to modifiy the code which calls for the counter.

Comment: This is a Windows batch file solution.

Comment: Any chance I can just have it show it on 1 batch, instead of attaching it to a different batch file? Like this needs a batch files to attach to, to show.

Comment: I'm afraid that that method would be a little bit more unaccurate than the method above. Just miliseconds.

Comment: Sorry but I have a tons of homework to do, I can't reply today.
Maybe you can seek help from others first. :P

Answer (score 0):

...

```
rem Change formatting for the start and end times
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%function_starttime%") do (
   set /A "start=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("%function_endtime%") do (
   set /A "end=(((%%a*60)+1%%b %% 100)*60+1%%c %% 100)*100+1%%d %% 100"
)

REM To avoid rollover errors, add 24 hours (in hundredths of a 
REM second) if the end time is past midnight
REM 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds * 100 = 8,640,000 hundredths of
REM a second
if %end% lss %start% set /A end=end+(24*60*60*100)

rem Calculate the elapsed time by subtracting values
set /A elapsed=end-start
```

...