# Benchmarking the CPU time of a python program in Windows 64-bit

Tags: python, windows-7, benchmarking

I need to get the CPU run time of my python application.

[How to measure execution time of command in windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line)

I came across the above thread earlier and learned about timeit. However, according to the download website, timeit is not supported in 64-bit Windows.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17657#top

time.clock() does not give CPU time in Windows.

Is there any easy way to get the CPU time of my python application?

Comment: What is the purpose? Do you actually need the CPU time or do you just want to know how long it takes? There are built in Python tools like the `timeit` and `cProfile` modules that can do that for you.

Comment: I need the CPU time to test the performance of two separate programs. Do you know what module can report the process time?

I know that time.clock() gives the CPU time in Unix, but not in Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this just to profile or benchmark your code, don't building your own, use a built in library.

http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html

Comment: The `profile` documentation explicitly says: "Note The profiler modules are designed to provide an execution profile for a given program, **not for benchmarking purposes** (for that, there is timeit for reasonably accurate results). "