# Can I split/merge output streams of subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, logging, stream, subprocess

I'm writing a wrapper class for use with a workflow manager. I would like to log output from an application (child process executed via `subprocess.Popen`) in a certain way:

- `stdout` of the child should go to a log file and to `stdout` of the parent,
- `stderr` of the child should go to a different logfile, but also to `stdout` of the parent.

I.e. all output from the child should end up merged on `stdout` (like with `subprocess.Popen(..., stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`, so I can reserve `stderr` for log messages from the wrapper itself. On the other hand, the child's streams should go to different files to allow separate validation.

I've tried using a "Tee" helper class to tie two streams (`stdout` and the log file) together, so that `Tee.write` writes to both streams. However, this cannot be passed to `Popen` because "subprocess" uses OS-level functions for writing (see here: http://bugs.python.org/issue1631).

The problem with my current solution (code snippet below, adapted mostly from [here](http://alexandre.deverteuil.net/blogue/archives/2011/04/03/monitor_python_subprocess_output_streams_in_real-time/index.html)) is that output on `stdout` may not appear in the right order.

How can I overcome this? Or should I use an altogether different approach?
(If I stick with the code below, how do I choose a value for the number of bytes in `os.read`?)

```
import subprocess, select, sys, os

call = ... # set this
process = subprocess.Popen(call, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
logs = {process.stdout: open("out.log", "w"), process.stderr: open("err.log", "w")}
done = {process.stdout: False, process.stderr: False}
while (process.poll() is None) or (not all(done.values())):
    ready = select.select([process.stdout, process.stderr], [], [])[0]
    for stream in ready:
        data = os.read(stream.fileno(), 1)
        if data:
            sys.stdout.write(data)
            logs[stream].write(data)
        else:
            done[stream] = True
logs[process.stdout].close()
logs[process.stderr].close()
```

By the way, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730201/1149840) using "fcntl" has not worked for me. And I couldn't quite figure out how to adapt [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/1149840) to my case yet, so I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `shell=True`, you can pass a command string to *subprocess* that includes pipes, redirections, and the *[tee command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29)*.

Comment: Thanks. After looking into it, something like this might be a solution: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6431  However, I would still be interested in a Python solution.