# Run multiple subprocesses in foreach loop? One at the time?

Tags: python, pygtk, subprocess, rsync

I'm creating a python script that runs rsync using subprocess and then gets the stdout and print it. 
The script runs mulitple rsync process bases on a conf file using this code:

```
for share in shares.split(', '):
  username = parser.get(share, 'username')
  sharename = parser.get(share, 'name')
  local = parser.get(share, 'local')
  remote = parser.get(share, 'remote')
  domain = parser.get(share, 'domain')
  remotedir = username+"@"+domain+":"+remote
  rsynclog = home + "/.bareshare/"+share+"rsync.log"
  os.system("cp "+rsynclog+" "+rsynclog+".1 && rm "+rsynclog) # MOve and remove old log
  rsync="rsync --bwlimit="+upload+" --stats --progress -azvv -e ssh "+local+" "+username+"@"+domain+":"+remote+" --log-file="+rsynclog+" &"
  # Run rsync of each share
  #         os.system(rsync) 
  self.rsyncRun = subprocess.Popen(["rsync","--bwlimit="+upload,"--stats","--progress","-azvv","-e","ssh",local,remotedir,"--log-file="+rsynclog], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I thinkg that this might not be the best thing to do - running multiple syncs at the sime time. How could I set up this so I wait for one process to finish before next one starts?

You can find my complete script here: https://github.com/danielholm/BareShare/blob/master/bareshare.py

Edit: And How do I make self.rsyncRun to die when done? When rsync is done with all the files, it seems like it continues altough it shouldnt be doing that.

Comment: Check out the [`Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling

```
self.rsyncRun.communicate()
```

will block the main process until the `rsyncRun` process has finished.

---

If you do not want the main process to block, then spawn a thread to handle the calls to `subprocess.Popen`:

```
import threading

def worker():
    for share in shares.split(', '):
        ...
        rsyncRun = subprocess.Popen(...)
        out, err = rsyncRun.communicate()

t = threading.Thread(target = worker)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
t.join()
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont want the main process to wait, just the rsync processes to wait for each other.

Comment: You could use the threading module to spawn a thread which handles the calls to `subprocess.Popen`. Then you could call `self.rsyncRun.communicate()` in the thread without blocking the main process.

Comment: So, I've added this function but I don't know how do get the output from the command anymore?

Comment: If you are willing to wait until `rsyncRun` is done, then you can simply access `out` and `err` after `t.join()`. But if you wish to see the output written to stdout and stderr by the `rsync` command as it is being produced, then you may need to use `select.select` (or something similar). See this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7730201/190597) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look.
EDIT: Just one more question: How do I kill the worker? It continues altough I send "gtk.main_quit()"
I have to both click on exit and press Ctrl+C to terminate the script.

Comment: Adding `t.daemon = True` before `t.start()` will cause the thread to terminate when the main process ends.