# Send subprocess.Popen stdout, stderr to logging module

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, subprocess

I want to start an application using Pythons subprocess.Popen and send the output of the applications stdout and stderr to the logging module in such fashion that it shows like `logging.INFO("This is whats in stdout")` every time the applications sends something/someline to stdout/stderr.

Since the application is a deamon it does ( and should ) not terminate.

Is there an easy way to achieve this or do I have to check the process output frequently with a separate thread?

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I took from [j-f-sebastian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35508812/7594717) as a reusable class:

```
import subprocess
from threading import Thread

class BackgroundPopen(subprocess.Popen):
    @staticmethod
    def prefix_handler(prefix, io):
        return lambda line: io.write(prefix + line)

    @staticmethod
    def _proxy_lines(pipe, handler):
        with pipe:
            for line in pipe:
                handler(line)

    def __init__(self, out_handler, err_handler, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['stdout'] = subprocess.PIPE
        kwargs['stderr'] = subprocess.PIPE
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        Thread(target=self._proxy_lines, args=[self.stdout, out_handler]).start()
        Thread(target=self._proxy_lines, args=[self.stderr, err_handler]).start()
```

Comment: In this example, `prefix_handler` is an example of a possible `out_handler` and `err_handler`; it does not override anything in `subprocess.Popen` and can be safely omitted.

Answer (score 4):

A thread is a simple and portable way to consume the output (not tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
from subprocess Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from threading import Thread

def consume_lines(pipe, consume):
    with pipe:
        for line in iter(pipe.readline, b''): #NOTE: workaround read-ahead bug
            consume(line)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
consume = lambda line: logging.info('this is whats in the output: %r', line)

process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1)
Thread(target=consume_lines, args=[process.stdout, consume]).start()
process.wait()
```

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, a separate thread is the way to go. That's how my [`sarge`](http://sarge.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#capturing-stdout-and-stderr-from-commands) library does it - it uses threads under the hood to capture output from the child process. In fact, I generally use two threads (one for `stdout` and one for `stderr`) unless I am merging the two output streams in the `subprocess.Popen` call.

Comment: This answer would be better with a code example (I know there is one in the linked page).

Comment: There's also an alternative method using non-blocking streams and just capturing it in the main thread while it waits for the child process to complete: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9115366/582917 What do you think of that vs the threads idea?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai that example uses `select`, so it's not ideal for Windows.