# Redirect subprocess stderr to stdout

Tags: python, stderr, subprocess

I want to redirect the stderr output of a subprocess to stdout. The constant [`STDOUT`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STDOUT) should do that, shouldn't it?

However,

```
$ python >/dev/null -c 'import subprocess;\
                        subprocess.call(["ls", "/404"],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)'
```

*does* output something. Why is that the case, and how do I get the error message on stdout?

Comment: BTW, it's fixed in python 3.5.

Comment: [Link to python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue22274)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**In Python < v3.5:**

A close read of the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0b4d0c2173ad/Lib/subprocess.py#l1284) gives the answer. In particular, the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STDOUT) is misleading when it says:

> `subprocess.STDOUT`
> Special value that (...) indicates that standard error should go into the same **handle** as standard output.

Since stdout is set to "default" (`-1`, technically) when `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` is evaluated, stderr is set to "default" as well. Unfortunately, this means that stderr output still goes to stderr.

To solve the problem, pass in the stdout file instead of `subprocess.STDOUT`:

```
$ python >/dev/null -c 'import subprocess,sys;subprocess.call(["ls", "/404"],
                        stderr=sys.stdout.buffer)'
```

Or, for compatibility with legacy 2.x versions of Python:

```
$ python >/dev/null -c 'import subprocess,sys;subprocess.call(["ls", "/404"],
                        stderr=sys.stdout.fileno())'
```

Comment: One can leave stderr as-is too: `stderr=sys.stderr.fileno()` . Nice example; I am going to simply use this technique in all my scripts. We have legacy Python 2.x; thus I'll know exactly where I told it to go without confusion.

Comment: For the record this is no-longer necessary in python 3.5+, as this case is automatically handled: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/75c1ca7b6c546ef674eb40bfe47f41e6045dc99b/Lib/subprocess.py#L1143-L1147

Answer (score 36):

Actually, using `subprocess.STDOUT` does **exactly** what is stated in the documentation: it redirects stderr to stdout so that e.g.

```
command = ["/bin/ls", "/tmp", "/notthere"]
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, bufsize=1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = ""
while (True):
    # Read line from stdout, break if EOF reached, append line to output
    line = process.stdout.readline()
    line = line.decode()
    if (line == ""): break
    output += line
```

results in variable `output` containing the process' output from both stdout and stderr.

`stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` redirects all stderr output **directly** to stdout of the calling process, which is a major difference.

---

**EDIT:** Updated code for newer Python versions:

```
command = ["/bin/ls", "/tmp", "/notthere"]
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, text=True, bufsize=1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = ""
while (True):
    # Read line from stdout, break if EOF reached, append line to output
    line = process.stdout.readline()
    if (line == ""): break
    output += line
```

Comment: -1 This case is irrelevant to the question which is about `stdout` being `None`. And `subprocess.STDOUT` does not redirect to the "calling console" (I think you mean the file handle 1 that the current process was given), as your own example shows - if you call Popen with `['ls', '/404']`, the [error message is not displayed](http://ideone.com/2JhcRT).

Comment: You are somewhat right. However, I don't think that this is irrelevant at all, since this is intended to clarify your post regarding the documentation being misleading - which isn't the case. I would have left a comment below your post, but a year ago I wasn't allowed to do so.

Comment: `python -c 'import subprocess,sys;subprocess.call(["ls", "/404"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)' 2>/dev/null` shows that the stderr of `ls` goes to stderr (file descriptor 2) because you will not see any output (presuming you have no `/404` on your system). That Python documentation really whiffed on that topic, and it's especially annoying to us shell scripters who are used to manipulating stdout/stderr in myriads of ways, and have to come here to SO just to figure out how to do something which should be simple and non-confusing.

Comment: It seems to me that the above here is the simpler solution and the intention of the OP.