# Capture stdout stderr of python subprocess, when it runs from cron or rc.local

Tags: python, cron, subprocess, stdout

I have problem accessing output (stderr stdout) of a command when I do lunch it via **cron or rc.local**

It works perfectly form regular shell, but fails via rc.local

```
cat /root/watchdog.py 
import subprocess
    cmd = ( 'echo "TEST" |gnokii --config /root/.config/gnokii/config --sendsms +123456789xx ')
    #p = subprocess.Popen([cmd, '2>&1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
    p = subprocess.Popen([cmd, '2>&1'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output = p.stdout.read()
    output += p.stderr.read()
    logFile = open("/root/logfile", 'a+')
    ##### 
    #Idea to read line by line:
    #output = ''
    #    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,''):
    #       print "captured line: %s" % line.rstrip()
    #       #logFile.write(line.rstrip())
    #       output += line
    logFile.write(output)
    logFile.close()
```

The output when run from console looks like:

```
/root/watchdog.py 
GNOKII Version 0.6.30
Cannot open logfile /root/.cache/gnokii/gnokii-errors
WARNING: cannot open logfile, logs will be directed to stderr
Send succeeded with reference 186!
```

in my rc.local

```
/root/watchdog.py  > /root/mywatchPY.out 2>&1 &
```

This looks interesting:
[Redirect subprocess stderr to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11495783/redirect-subprocess-stderr-to-stdout)
but it does not solve the problem.

Any idea howto capture sdterr/stdout of subprocess run without full shell?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- pass the command and its args as a string when `shell=True` otherwise the args are passed to the shell itself instead of the command
- you should use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` instead of `2>&1` if you meant to apply the latter to the whole pipeline and not just the last command in it
- use `p.communicate()` instead of `p.stdout.read()`, `p.stderr.read()` otherwise the subprocess may stall if any of OS pipe buffers fill up
- if you want to redirect the output to a file then you do not need to save it as a string first

```py
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

with open("/root/logfile", 'ab', 0) as logfile:
    p = Popen(shlex.split('gnokii ... +123456789xx'), 
              stdin=PIPE, stdout=logfile, stderr=STDOUT)
    p.communicate(b'TEST')
```

[Redirect subprocess stderr to stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11495783/4279) doesn't apply because you redirect `stdout` explicitly.