# printing terminal outputs to text file

Tags: python

Im trying to send all my outputs to a file,not exclusively *print* statements but all statements,I'm running an algorithm which gives outputs of its own and some logger outputs,

Right now Im trying

```
f = open('/mnt/sdc1/Ryan/Test/output_logs/{}.txt'.format(file),'w')
sys.stdout=f
```

but this outputs only the print statements,

I have also tried experimenting with

```
f = open('/mnt/sdc1/Ryan/Test/output_logs/{}.txt'.format(file),'w')
sys.stderr=f
```

but this too does not give me *everything* that the terminal outputs,
Any suggestions would be helpful,Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does 'not everything' mean? please be more precise. (did you try to `f.flush()` your out file from time to time?).

Comment: stdout and stderr are two different output streams. For your "everything" you need to catch them both, not one at a time.

Comment: this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602878/how-to-handle-both-with-open-and-sys-stdout-nicely

Comment: I did not do f.flush(), by 'not everything' i mean when i do sys.stdout, i only get ouptuts where i have explicitly specified print in my python file,and when i try sys.stderr ,I dont get the print ones and also i dont get the logger ones,Sorry if i was unclear

Comment: @usr2564301 can i  catch them both and put them in one text file?

Comment: Well I don't know about you but others can: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38776104/2564301, for example.