# How to log outputs and errors to file without knowing where errors will occur

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, error-handling, error-logging

I have a long script which I run on a remote server and I want to log all outputs as well as error messages to a file.

1. I know how to log all terminal outputs (e.g. print()) to a .txt file:

```
# in script:
import sys sys.stdout = open('./myfile.txt', 'w')
# ... 
sys.stdout.close()

# in terminal:
python myscript.py > ./myfile.txt
```

This writes all print() outputs to a file, which I want. But it does not write error messages to the file in case it fails.

2. I know how to log errors

```
import logging
try:
   # ...
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
   logging.error(e)  # ERROR:root:division by zero
```

The problem with all solutions linked to the logging module is, that I need to know where the error will occur to wrap it in a logging.error() function. But I don't always know where my errors will occur.

=> How do I (1) write all outputs and (2) the error that makes my script fail to a file?

Comment: install [sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/), its simple and easy, also they do offer a free subscription, i myself have been using it for the past 2 months and i love it. error logging as never been easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself: just type this in the terminal and make sure that you have a log.text file in the right directory. No changes in the script needed.

```
python script.py &> ./log.txt
```

Inspired from this question: [Redirect stdout and stderr to same file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776104/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-same-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect python error output `sys.stderr` to a file:

```
import sys

sys.stderr = open("errors.txt", "w")
```

Comment: ah right thanks, I didn't know that there is a separate sys.stderr for errors next to sys.stdout. Is it possible to write both standard outputs and errors to the same file? what would the code look like?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to create a new file that contains all the logs you want to write. Configuration would look something like this:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='std.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

this will output the logging messages to the std.log file

Comment: So in this case, I first manually crate a std.log file in my directory and then after running this code every output from the following code (prints, errors, warnings etc.) are written to this file?