# How fast c++ file is fulfilled?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to measure execution time of command in windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673523/how-to-measure-execution-time-of-command-in-windows-command-line)

is there a program which counts how fast .exe file is fulfilled? For example, if I must write c++ that takes one number from input file, multiply it with 2 and outputs in output file. And if I start c++ program, I can't tell how fast it is completed, cause for me it seems like 0.1 sec - blinking window. So is there any chance telling exactly time of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Linux and other unices you can use the time command.

```
time foo.exe

real    0m0.053s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

I am sure there's some equivalent for Windows as well.

Answer (score 2):

On Unix, the `time` command will tell you how long a command took, in terms of User, System, and overall time.